# improve in coding saving how to check if two line segments are crossing in Python

Tags: python, coding-style, geometry, line

Consider the following example of crossing lines:

```
l1 = ((20,5),(40,20))
l2 = ((20,20),(40,5))
l3 = ((30,30),(30,5)) # vertical line
```

I developed the following code to compute the x,y of the crossing point (see theoretical details)

```
def gradient(l):
    """Returns gradient 'm' of a line"""
    m = None
    # Ensure that the line is not vertical
    if l[0][0] != l[1][0]:
        m = (1./(l[0][0]-l[1][0]))*(l[0][1] - l[1][1])
        return m

def parallel(l1,l2):
    if gradient(l1) != gradient(l2):
        return False
    return True


def intersect(l):
    """Returns intersect (b) of a line using the equation of
    a line in slope and intercepet form (y = mx+b)"""
    return l[0][1] - (gradient(l)*l[0][0])


def line_intersection(l1,l2):
    """Returns the intersection point (x,y) of two line segments. Returns False
    for parallel lines"""
    # Not parallel
    if not parallel(l1,l2):
        if gradient(l1) is not None and gradient(l2) is not None:
            x = (1./(gradient(l1) - gradient(l2))) * (intersect(l2) - intersect(l1))
            y = (gradient(l1)*x) + intersect(l1)
        else:
            if gradient(l1) is None:
                x = l1[0][0]
                y = (gradient(l2)*x) + intersect(l2)
            elif gradient(l2) is None:
                x = l2[0][0]
                y = (gradient(l1)*x) + intersect(l1)
        return (x,y)
    else:
        return False
```

example session:

```
>>> line_intersection(l1,l2)
(30.0, 12.5)
>>> line_intersection(l2,l3)
(30, 12.5)
```

I wish to improve in an efficient style my code in the case of line segments which have a limited length, and they might not actually intersect.

```
l1 = ((4,4),(10,10)) 
l2 = ((11,5),(5,11))
l3 = ((11,5),(9,7))

line_intersection(l1,l2) #valid
(8.0, 8.0)
line_intersection(l1,l3) # they don't cross each other
(8.0, 8.0)
line_intersection(l2,l3) #line parallel
False
```

my **inelegant** solution is the follow.

```
def crosses(l1,l2):
    if not parallel(l1,l2):
        x = line_intersection(l1,l2)[0]
        xranges = [max(min(l1[0][0],l1[1][0]),min(l2[0][0],l2[1][0])),min(max(l1[0][0],l1[1][0]),max(l2[0][0],l2[1][0]))]
        if min(xranges) <= x <= max(xranges):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False


crosses(l1,l2)
True
crosses(l2,l3)
False
```

i am looking if it's possible to improve the style of my functions in python

Comment: Since you're only dealing with straight structures, checking to see if the intersection point is within a the x-coordinates of one of the lines should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @WaleedKhan. I need to find a save coding function

Comment: just a hint.. do not use slope/intersect. Write your lines in parametric form x1 = p11 (1-a)/2 + p12 (1+a)/2 x2 = p21 (1-b)/2+p22(1+b)/2 solve for a,b and check that a,b are both in range -1,1. That way you dont need to treat the vertical line as a special case.

Comment: This question is either off-topic (should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com) or a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838329/how-can-i-check-if-two-segments-intersect, depending on how you look at it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Any code that returns the right answer is pretty awesome in my book. Well done.

Here are a few suggestions:

```
def parallel(l1,l2):
    if gradient(l1) != gradient(l2):
        return False
    return True
```

can be written as

```
def parallel(l1,l2):
    return gradient(l1) == gradient(l2)
```

Similarly,

```
if min(xranges) <= x <= max(xranges):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

can be written as

```
return min(xranges) <= x <= max(xranges)
```

---

Avoid integer indexing whenever possible, especially double-level integer indexing like `l1[0][0]`.

Words or variable names are easier to read and understand than integer indices.

One way around integer indexing is to use "tuple-unpacking":

```
(x1, y1), (x2, y2) = l1
```

And then `l1[0][0]` becomes `x1`.
This could improve the readability of your code in the `gradient` and `crosses` functions.

---

There are two cases when the lines are parallel. If the lines are not collinear,
then they never intersect. But if the lines are collinear, they intersect
everywhere.

It does not seem accurate to say

```
line_intersection(line, line)
```

is `False` when the lines are collinear. It seems even more wrong (if such a thing were possible :)) when the lines in question are the exact same line.

I suggest returning an arbitrary point of intersection if the lines are
collinear, and `None` if the lines are parallel but non-collinear.

---

There is a bug that can arise when floats are compared for equality:

```
    In [81]: 1.2 - 1.0 == 0.2
    Out[81]: False
```

This is not a bug in Python, but rather it is [a problem caused by the internal representation of floats](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm) which affects all floating point computation done in any language. It can introduce a bug into any code that tries to compare floats for equality -- such as here:

```
def parallel(l1,l2):
    if gradient(l1) == gradient(l2): ...
```

So instead of comparing the equality of floats, the best we can do is test if two
floats are near each other within some level of tolerance. For example,

```
def near(a, b, rtol=1e-5, atol=1e-8):
    # Essentially borrowed from NumPy 
    return abs(a - b) < (atol + rtol * abs(b))

def parallel(l1,l2):
    if near(gradient(l1), gradient(l2)): ...
```

---

The [PEP8 style guide says](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid),

> Never use the characters 'l' (lowercase letter el), 'O' (uppercase
>   letter oh), or 'I' (uppercase letter eye) as single character variable
>   names.
>
> In some fonts, these characters are indistinguishable from the
>   numerals one and zero.

So instead of `l1` I suggest `line1`.

---

Now, as @george pointed out, there are a number of places where the code handles
vertical lines as a special case (`if gradient is None`.)  If we use the
parametric form of the line, we can handle *all* lines the same way. The code
will be simpler because the math will be simpler.

If you know two points on a line, `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`, 
then the parametric form of the line is

```
l(t) = (x1, y1)*(1-t) + (x2, y2)*t
```

where `t` is a scalar. As `t` varies you get different points on the line. Notice some pertinent facts about the parametric form:

- When `t = 1`, the **first** term on the right-hand side drops out, so you
  are left with `(x2, y2)`.
- When `t = 0`, the **second** term on the right-hand side drops out, so you are left
  with `(x1, y1)*(1-0) = (x1, y1)`.
- The right-hand side of the equation depends **linearly** on `t`. There
  are no `t**2` terms or any other non-linear dependence on `t`. **So the parametric form describes a line**.

---

**Why is the parametric form of the line powerful?**

- The points inside the line segment (x1, y1) to (x2, y2) correspond to
  `t` values between 0 and 1 (inclusive). All other values of `t`
  correspond to points outside the line segment.
- Notice also that vertical lines are nothing special as far as the
  parametric form is concerned. You do not have to worry about infinite
  slopes. *Every line can be treated the same way*.

---

**How can we leverage this fact?**

If we have two lines in parametric form:

```
l1(t) = (x1, y1)*(1-t) + (x2, y2)*t

l2(s) = (u1, v1)*(1-s) + (u2, v2)*s
```

(think of x1, y1, x2, y2, u1, v1, u2, v2 as given constants), then the lines intersect when

```
l1(t) = l2(s)
```

Now, `l1(t)` is a two-dimensional point. `l1(t) = l2(s)` is a two-dimensional equation. There is an equation for the `x`-coordinate and an equation for the `y`-coordinate built into `l1(t) = l2(s)`.
So we really have two equations, and two unknowns (`t` and `s`).
We can solve these equations for `t` and `s`! (Hopefully. If the lines do not intersect, then there is no solution for `t` and `s`.

---

So let's do some math :)

```
l1(t) = (x1, y1) + (x2-x1, y2-y1)*t
l2(s) = (u1, v1) + (u2-u1, v2-v1)*s
```

`l1(t) = l2(s)` implies two scalar equations:

```
x1 + (x2-x1)*t = u1 + (u2-u1)*s
y1 + (y2-y1)*t = v1 + (v2-v1)*s

(x2-x1)*t - (u2-u1)*s = u1-x1
(y2-y1)*t - (v2-v1)*s = v1-y1
```

And we can rewrite that as a matrix equation:

[image]

Using [Cramer's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Explicit_formulas_for_small_systems) we can solve for `t` and `s`: If

[image]

then

[image]

[image]

Note that Cramer's rule is valid from a mathematical point of view, (and is easy to code) but it has [poor numerical properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Cramer.27s_rule) (see also [GEPP vs Cramer's Rule](https://books.google.com/books?id=5tv3HdF-0N8C&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=numerical+instability+Cramer%27s+rule&source=bl&ots=IGq1WXdbU7&sig=U8DiFxdyjWJhwYRXXRRDZkBpPsw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xh-hVZn7HoafNruzg4gI&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=numerical%20instability%20Cramer%27s%20rule&f=false)). For serious applications, use [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Solving_linear_equations), or LAPACK (available through NumPy).

---

So we can code it up as follows:

```
def line_intersection(line1, line2):
    """
    Return the coordinates of a point of intersection given two lines.
    Return None if the lines are parallel, but non-collinear.
    Return an arbitrary point of intersection if the lines are collinear.

    Parameters:
    line1 and line2: lines given by 2 points (a 2-tuple of (x,y)-coords).
    """
    (x1,y1), (x2,y2) = line1
    (u1,v1), (u2,v2) = line2
    (a,b), (c,d) = (x2-x1, u1-u2), (y2-y1, v1-v2)
    e, f = u1-x1, v1-y1
    # Solve ((a,b), (c,d)) * (t,s) = (e,f)
    denom = float(a*d - b*c)
    if near(denom, 0):
        # parallel
        # If collinear, the equation is solvable with t = 0.
        # When t=0, s would have to equal e/b and f/d
        if near(float(e)/b, float(f)/d):
            # collinear
            px = x1
            py = y1
        else:
            return None
    else:
        t = (e*d - b*f)/denom
        # s = (a*f - e*c)/denom
        px = x1 + t*(x2-x1)
        py = y1 + t*(y2-y1)
    return px, py


def crosses(line1, line2):
    """
    Return True if line segment line1 intersects line segment line2 and 
    line1 and line2 are not parallel.
    """
    (x1,y1), (x2,y2) = line1
    (u1,v1), (u2,v2) = line2
    (a,b), (c,d) = (x2-x1, u1-u2), (y2-y1, v1-v2)
    e, f = u1-x1, v1-y1
    denom = float(a*d - b*c)
    if near(denom, 0):
        # parallel
        return False
    else:
        t = (e*d - b*f)/denom
        s = (a*f - e*c)/denom
        # When 0<=t<=1 and 0<=s<=1 the point of intersection occurs within the
        # line segments
        return 0<=t<=1 and 0<=s<=1

def near(a, b, rtol=1e-5, atol=1e-8):
    return abs(a - b) < (atol + rtol * abs(b))

line1 = ((4,4),(10,10)) 
line2 = ((11,5),(5,11))
line3 = ((11,5),(9,7))
line4 = ((4,0),(10,6)) 

assert all(near(a,b) for a,b in zip(line_intersection(line1,line2), (8.0, 8.0)))
assert all(near(a,b) for a,b in zip(line_intersection(line1,line3), (8.0, 8.0)))
assert all(near(a,b) for a,b in zip(line_intersection(line2,line3), (11, 5)))

assert line_intersection(line1, line4) == None # parallel, non-collinear
assert crosses(line1,line2) == True
assert crosses(line2,line3) == False
```