# Checking if a point is inside a polygon

Tags: python, geometry, polygon, point

I have a class describing a Point (has 2 coordinates x and y) and a class describing a Polygon which has a list of Points which correspond to corners (self.corners)
I need to check if a Point is in a Polygon

Here is the function that is supposed to check if the Point is in the Polygon. I am using the Ray Casting Method

```
def in_me(self, point):
        result = False
        n = len(self.corners)
        p1x = int(self.corners[0].x)
        p1y = int(self.corners[0].y)
        for i in range(n+1):
            p2x = int(self.corners[i % n].x)
            p2y = int(self.corners[i % n].y)
            if point.y > min(p1y,p2y):
                if point.x <= max(p1x,p2x):
                    if p1y != p2y:
                        xinters = (point.y-p1y)*(p2x-p1x)/(p2y-p1y)+p1x
                        print xinters
                    if p1x == p2x or point.x <= xinters:
                        result = not result
            p1x,p1y = p2x,p2y
         return result
```

I run a test with following shape and point:

```
PG1 = (0,0), (0,2), (2,2), (2,0)
point = (1,1)
```

The script happily returns False even though the point it within the line. I am unable to find the mistake

Comment: Might be because you're using "/" on integers, which returns an integer (rounded down).  You should do all computations with floats instead.  Also, if p1y == p2y, xinters might not be defined but still used just afterwards.

Comment: Better yet: don't divide at all. Instead of computing `xinters`, check if `(point.x - p1x)*(p2y-p1y) <= (point.y-p1y)*(p2x-p1x)`. However, casting the vertex coordinates to integers could introduce errors if they aren't already integers to start with.

Comment: ...or use Python 3, which doesn't truncate to integers on division.

Comment: how would using `(point.x - p1x)*(p2y-p1y) <= (point.y-p1y)*(p2x-p1x)` make the actual code look like?

Since it is a homework assignment, then we have to use Python 2.7 :(

Comment: @Ulrich & helena: Python 3 division can be enabled in Python 2 using `from __future__ import division`. Another alternative is to just `float()` either the numerator or denominator (or a term in one of them in this case).

Answer (score 66):

I would suggest using the [`Path`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path) class from `matplotlib`

```
import matplotlib.path as mplPath
import numpy as np

poly = [190, 50, 500, 310]
bbPath = mplPath.Path(np.array([[poly[0], poly[1]],
                     [poly[1], poly[2]],
                     [poly[2], poly[3]],
                     [poly[3], poly[0]]]))

bbPath.contains_point((200, 100))
```

(There is also a `contains_points` function if you want to test for multiple points)

Comment: For this to work, you must first `import numpy as np`

Comment: Anyone checked performance of `contains_points` against a pure Python implementation ?

Comment: Something's wrong, using array = [[100,100],[200,100],[200,200],[100,200],[100,100]] it gives False for point 100,100 and true for point 200,200

Comment: Why the variable name 'bbPath'?  
if (Does 'bb' abbreviate something?):
what does 'bb' abbreviate?

Comment: `bb` means bounding box even though the polygon very like wont be a box :)

Comment: @Maciek the answer to your question is in [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.contains_point): "The result is undefined for points exactly at the boundary"

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy yes, benchmarks are at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399381/

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to suggest some other changes there:

```
def contains(self, point):
    if not self.corners:
        return False

    def lines():
        p0 = self.corners[-1]
        for p1 in self.corners:
            yield p0, p1
            p0 = p1

    for p1, p2 in lines():
        ... # perform actual checks here
```

Notes:

- A polygon with 5 corners also has 5 bounding lines, not 6, your loop is one off.
- Using a separate generator expression makes clear that you are checking each line in turn.
- Checking for an empty number of lines was added. However, how to treat zero-length lines and polygons with a single corner is still open.
- I'd also consider making the lines() function a normal member instead of a nested utility.
- Instead of the many nested if structures, you could also check for the inverse and then `continue` or use `and`.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to solve the same problem for my project and I got this code from someone in my network.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# routine for performing the "point in polygon" inclusion test

# Copyright 2001, softSurfer (www.softsurfer.com)
# This code may be freely used and modified for any purpose
# providing that this copyright notice is included with it.
# SoftSurfer makes no warranty for this code, and cannot be held
# liable for any real or imagined damage resulting from its use.
# Users of this code must verify correctness for their application.

# translated to Python by Maciej Kalisiak <mac@dgp.toronto.edu>

#   a Point is represented as a tuple: (x,y)

#===================================================================

# is_left(): tests if a point is Left|On|Right of an infinite line.

#   Input: three points P0, P1, and P2
#   Return: >0 for P2 left of the line through P0 and P1
#           =0 for P2 on the line
#           <0 for P2 right of the line
#   See: the January 2001 Algorithm "Area of 2D and 3D Triangles and Polygons"

def is_left(P0, P1, P2):
    return (P1[0] - P0[0]) * (P2[1] - P0[1]) - (P2[0] - P0[0]) * (P1[1] - P0[1])

#===================================================================

# cn_PnPoly(): crossing number test for a point in a polygon
#     Input:  P = a point,
#             V[] = vertex points of a polygon
#     Return: 0 = outside, 1 = inside
# This code is patterned after [Franklin, 2000]

def cn_PnPoly(P, V):
    cn = 0    # the crossing number counter

    # repeat the first vertex at end
    V = tuple(V[:])+(V[0],)

    # loop through all edges of the polygon
    for i in range(len(V)-1):   # edge from V[i] to V[i+1]
        if ((V[i][1] <= P[1] and V[i+1][1] > P[1])   # an upward crossing
            or (V[i][1] > P[1] and V[i+1][1] <= P[1])):  # a downward crossing
            # compute the actual edge-ray intersect x-coordinate
            vt = (P[1] - V[i][1]) / float(V[i+1][1] - V[i][1])
            if P[0] < V[i][0] + vt * (V[i+1][0] - V[i][0]): # P[0] < intersect
                cn += 1  # a valid crossing of y=P[1] right of P[0]

    return cn % 2   # 0 if even (out), and 1 if odd (in)

#===================================================================

# wn_PnPoly(): winding number test for a point in a polygon
#     Input:  P = a point,
#             V[] = vertex points of a polygon
#     Return: wn = the winding number (=0 only if P is outside V[])

def wn_PnPoly(P, V):
    wn = 0   # the winding number counter

    # repeat the first vertex at end
    V = tuple(V[:]) + (V[0],)

    # loop through all edges of the polygon
    for i in range(len(V)-1):     # edge from V[i] to V[i+1]
        if V[i][1] <= P[1]:        # start y <= P[1]
            if V[i+1][1] > P[1]:     # an upward crossing
                if is_left(V[i], V[i+1], P) > 0: # P left of edge
                    wn += 1           # have a valid up intersect
        else:                      # start y > P[1] (no test needed)
            if V[i+1][1] <= P[1]:    # a downward crossing
                if is_left(V[i], V[i+1], P) < 0: # P right of edge
                    wn -= 1           # have a valid down intersect
    return wn
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Iterate over all the segments in the polygon
- Check whether they intersect with a ray going in the increasing-x direction

Using the `intersect` function from [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838329/how-can-i-check-if-two-segments-intersect)

```
def ccw(A,B,C):
    return (C.y-A.y) * (B.x-A.x) > (B.y-A.y) * (C.x-A.x)

# Return true if line segments AB and CD intersect
def intersect(A,B,C,D):
    return ccw(A,C,D) != ccw(B,C,D) and ccw(A,B,C) != ccw(A,B,D)

def point_in_polygon(pt, poly, inf):
    result = False
    for i in range(len(poly.corners)-1):
        if intersect((poly.corners[i].x, poly.corners[i].y), ( poly.corners[i+1].x, poly.corners[i+1].y), (pt.x, pt.y), (inf, pt.y)):
            result = not result
    if intersect((poly.corners[-1].x, poly.corners[-1].y), (poly.corners[0].x, poly.corners[0].y), (pt.x, pt.y), (inf, pt.y)):
        result = not result
    return result
```

Please note that the `inf` parameter should be the maximum point in the x axis in your figure.

Comment: This is incorrect, doesn't work for point [2, 5] with polygon [8, 6], [11, 10], [16, 5], [11, 3]

Edit: The issue is probably that the ray goes directly through a point of the polygon, causing two polygon line segments to be toggling `result`, turning it back to its previous state