# Removing points inside several polygons

Tags: python, text-files, polygon

**THE DATA:** I have co-ordinates of two variables `a` and `b` of length 100,000 each and I have a text file containing the co-ordinates of several polygons.

**I would like to now remove all those points of a and b that are inside the different polygons.**

To do so, I am trying to use [THE CODE FROM THIS ANSWER IN STACKOVERFLOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625507/python-checking-if-point-is-inside-a-polygon) which does it for one point and one polygon.

**The method I have chalked out to go about the problem for several points and several polygons is this:**

- Take the **co-ordinates of the first polygon**
- Run the function for all the 100,000 points of `a and b` and **if they are inside, then append them to a list, which I can use later to compare with the original a and b**
- Perform the **above two steps with the co-ordinates of the second polygon and so on...**

Now I have two problems facing me, which I don't know how to proceed with.

1. The text file containing the co-ordinates of the polygons looks like this:

   **020241-041200 4** 30.83 -3.69 30.82 -3.69 30.82 -3.73 30.83 -3.73

   **020241-041200 12** 30.91 -4.03 30.89 -4.03 30.85 -4.05 30.83 -4.07 30.82 -4.09 30.84 -4.16 30.89 -4.19 30.96 -4.16 30.97 -4.13 30.97 -4.08 30.95 -4.05 30.93 -4.04

   Here **(020241-041200) is the ID** of the polygon, and **(4) is the number of corners the polygon has,** **30.83 is the X co-ordinate of the first corner** and **-3.69 is the Y co-ordinate of the first corner** and so on.

   I want to skip the first two columns so that I can only consider the X,Y co-ordinates of the polygons. How do I do that?
2. **The polygons are not of the same shape**, as you can see, **the second polygon has 12 corners** compared to 4 in the first one.

THE 100,000 POINTS OF `a and b` LOOK LIKE THIS [image: THE 100,000 POINTS OF a AND b LOOK LIKE THIS]

If there is any convenient way, other than the solution I have given above, it would also be useful.

**All I want are, those points of a and b that are outside the polygons.**

Comment: Check out the sweepline algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "those points of a and b that are outside the polygons" do you mean outside *all* of the polygons or outside *any* of the polygons?

Here is:

1. A routine to read in the polygon points and create the appropriate data structure for use with the `point_in_poly` function.
2. A routine to check if a point is in any of the polygons.

Here is the routine to read the polygon points from a file:

```
def readPolygons(path):
  polygons = []
  with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:                                         # (1)
      words = [ float(y) for y in (line.split())[2:] ]     # (2)
      poly = zip (words[::2], words[1::2])                 # (3)
      if len(poly):                                        # (4)
        polygons.append(poly)
  return polygons
```

Each polygon is represented as a list of pairs of floats, and the routine returns a list of polygons.

Notes:

1. Iterate over all of the lines in the file.
2. Split the line into words, drop the first two words with `[2:]` and convert each word to a float.
3. Create a list of pairs, taking the 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc as the x coordinates and the 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc as the y coordinates.
4. Ignore blank lines.

Here is the routine to check if a point is in any polygon:

```
def inAnyPolygon(x,y,polygons):
  for p in polygons:
    if point_in_poly(x,y,p):
      return True
  return False
```

If your criteria is "in all the polygons", then use:

```
def inAllPolygons(x,y,polygons):
  for p in polygons:
    if not point_in_poly(x,y,p):
      return False
  return True
```

Update: if you have a list of points `points`, you can create another list containing those points which are not in any of the polygons with:

```
outliers = []
for p in points:
  (x,y) = p
  if not inAnyPolygons(x,y,polygons):
    outliers.append(p)
return outliers
```

If `a` and `b` are lists of numbers representing the x and y coordinates respectively of the 100000 points, here is the code to find the outliers:

```
outliers = []
for (x,y) in zip(a,b):
  if not inAnyPolygons(x,y,polygons):
    outliers.append((x,y))
return outliers
```

Comment: "those points of a and b that are outside the polygons": I want all those points outside all of my polygons. I shall immediately perform your code and check !!!

Comment: I have `a and b` which are two variables with 100,000 points each. Your `readPolygons` now gives me a tuple with the co-ordinates of the polygons!!! Now I need to get `a_outside` and `b_outside`, i.e. the points outside the polygons. BTW by `points`, do you mean my `a and b`?

Comment: Give me an example of what `a` and `b` look like.

Comment: They are there in the figure in the question! `a` is a list of 100,000 points ranging from 30.0-38.0 and `b` is a list of 100,000 points ranging from -11.0 to -3.7. The co-ordinates of the several polygons also lie within this range.

Comment: `readPolygons` returns a list of "polygons" where each "polygon" is a list of pairs of numbers, and it does that because in the  `point_in_polygon` function a polygon is represented by a list of pairs of numbers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65205/discussion-between-thepredator-and-user5402).

Comment: Please give me a concrete example for `a` and `b`. Are they lists? Are the lists of numbers? Are they lists of pairs of numbers? It is not clear what they are.

Comment: example, `a=array([ 36.34511603,  34.42881285,  32.00052102,  35.20495323,
        35.80194333,  36.79451664,  32.08352502,  35.49977049,  33.60233316])`