# How to check in matplotlib if a point lies inside a polygon in polar coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a closed path generated in polar coordinates as shown below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib qt

horizon_az = np.array([41, 66, 115, 220, 300, 41])
horizon_alt = np.array([16, 15, 10, 23, 33, 16])

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(horizon_az * np.pi / 180, horizon_alt, 'r', linewidth=3)
```

How can I check if a specific point say (0, 0) is inside this path?

While one can use the `Path.contains_point` method from `matplotlib.path` for Cartesian coordinates [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625507/python-checking-if-point-is-inside-a-polygon), how does one take into account the polar coordinate transformation?
[image: Closed Path in Polar Coordinates]

Answer (score -1):

Why not translate your coordinates into Cartesian and use the solution you cited?

```
horizon_x = horizon_alt * np.cos(horizon_az * np.pi / 180)
horizon_y = horizon_alt * np.sin(horizon_az * np.pi / 180)
```

Comment: Yes, I could do that. However, I was wondering if there was a direct way internal to matplotlib that would do the coordinate transform for me directly.