# How to find if the coordinates of interest are found inside a polygon or not?

Tags: python, function

I was writing a  code to find out whether the coordinates am interested is found inside or outside a rectangle. I found that there is a function "contain_points", which will serve the purpose, equivalent of "inpolygon" in Matlab. I was unable to find any document on implementation or example of this function. Can anyone suggest how this works?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399381/whats-the-fastest-way-of-checking-if-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) library. It is the de facto standard when dealing with 2D polygons in python (and many other languages, since it it a wrapping of GEOS C++ library).

An example of what you want:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
p = Point(0.0, 0.0)
poly = Polygon([(1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1), (1, -1)])
is_included = poly.contains(p)
```

`is_included` is `True` now.

Comment: can you look at the answer posted and give  comments?