# How can I count the number of polygons a shape intersects?

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas

I have a very large dataset with a polygons and points with buffers around them. I would like to creat a new column in the points data which includes the number of polygons that point's buffer intersects.

Heres a simplified example:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gp
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Create polygons and points ##

df = gp.GeoDataFrame([['a',Polygon([(1, 0), (1, 1), (2,2), (1,2)])],
                     ['b',Polygon([(1, 0.25), (2,1.25), (3,0.25)])]],
                     columns = ['name','geometry'])
df = gp.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = 'geometry')

points = gp.GeoDataFrame( [['box', Point(1.5, 1.115), 4],
                        ['triangle', Point(2.5,1.25), 8]],
                     columns=['name', 'geometry', 'value'], 
                     geometry='geometry')

##Set a buffer around the points##

buf = points.buffer(0.5)
points['buffer'] = buf
points = points.drop(['geometry'], axis = 1) 
points = points.rename(columns = {'buffer': 'geometry'})
```

This data looks like this:
[image]
What I'd like to do is create another column in the points dataframe that includes the number of polygons that point intersects.

I've tried utilising a for loop as such:

```
points['intersect'] = []
for geo1 in points['geometry']:
    for geo2 in df['geometry']:
        if geo1.intersects(geo2):
            points['intersect'].append('1')
```

Which I would then sum to get the total number of intersects.
However, I get the error: 'Length of values does not match length of index'. I know this is because it is attempting to assign three rows of data to a frame with only two rows.

How can I aggrigate the counts so the first point is assigned a value of 2 and the second a value of 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have large dataset, I would go for solution using rtree spatial index, something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gp
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Create polygons and points ##

df = gp.GeoDataFrame([['a',Polygon([(1, 0), (1, 1), (2,2), (1,2)])],
                     ['b',Polygon([(1, 0.25), (2,1.25), (3,0.25)])]],
                     columns = ['name','geometry'])
df = gp.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = 'geometry')

points = gp.GeoDataFrame( [['box', Point(1.5, 1.115), 4],
                        ['triangle', Point(2.5,1.25), 8]],
                     columns=['name', 'geometry', 'value'], 
                     geometry='geometry')

# generate spatial index
sindex = df.sindex
# define empty list for results
results_list = []
# iterate over the points
for index, row in points.iterrows():
    buffer = row['geometry'].buffer(0.5)  # buffer
    # find approximate matches with r-tree, then precise matches from those approximate ones
    possible_matches_index = list(sindex.intersection(buffer.bounds))
    possible_matches = df.iloc[possible_matches_index]
    precise_matches = possible_matches[possible_matches.intersects(buffer)]
    results_list.append(len(precise_matches))
# add list of results as a new column
points['polygons'] = pd.Series(results_list)
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you. Am I right in thinking this speeds up the process because the possible_matches search will rule out a great deal of polygons in the large dataset?

Comment: Exactly. If you want explanation check this https://geoffboeing.com/2016/10/r-tree-spatial-index-python/

Comment: Excellent, I definitly will! Thansk again.