# Segment a pandas DataFrame containing lat/lng by a given geojson

Tags: python, pandas, geojson

I have a `DataFrame` containing the columns `lat` and `lng`. I also have `FeatureCollection` geojson that contains a polygon. Given this polygon, how can I segment my `df` and select only the rows that are within the given polygon in an efficient way? I want to avoid looping over the `df` and checking each element manually.

```
d = {'lat' : [0,0.1,-0.1,0.4],
    'lng' : [50,50.1,49.6,49.5]}


df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

This is the feature collection that displays 1 polygon and the 4 points. As you can see, only the last point is outside.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              0,
              49
            ],
            [
              0.6,
              50
            ],
            [
              0.1,
              52
            ],
            [
              -1,
              51
            ],
            [
              0,
              49
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          0,
          50
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          0.1,
          50.1
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.1,
          49.6
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          0.4,
          49.5
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[this map](http://geojson.io/#id=gist:otmezger/30f0f6ce0fd4c1f88690ddda3322f2ac&map=7/50.524/-0.200) displays the polygon and points.

Edit: 
The following is the code that I have at the moment, but as you can expect, it is very slow.

```
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point
# check each polygon to see if it contains the point
for feature in feature_collection['features']:
    polygon = shape(feature['geometry'])
    for index, row in dfr.iterrows():
        point = Point(row.location_lng, row.location_lat)
        if polygon.contains(point):
            print('Found containing polygon:', feature)
```

where `dfr` is my `DataFrame` containing `location_lat` and `location_lng`. The `feature_collection` is a geojson Feature Collection that has only polygons (note that the example of geojson above is just for explaining the question, it only has 1 polygon and has some points to ilustrate the question).

Comment: Is this link relevant?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399381/whats-the-fastest-way-of-checking-if-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-in-python

Comment: thanks @erncyp that did not help me, as it uses matplotlib and I don't want to go that way. I would prefer doing it with a pandas like approach.

Comment: Did you create the dataframe `df` from `feature_collection`? if yes how? and in your code you use `iterrows` on `dfr` not `df`, is it the same?

Comment: @Ben.T thanks for the questions. I'll try to clarify. The example above is just to explain the task. In general, I have a large dataframe (`dfr`) and a large feature collection, containing only polygons. I'll try to edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have you dataframe `dfr` like:

```
   location_lat  location_lng
0           0.0          50.0
1           0.1          50.1
2          -0.1          49.6
3           0.4          49.5
```

and the `feature_collection` containing polygons such as:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[[0,49],[0.6,50],[0.1,52],[-1,51],[0,49]]]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[[0,50],[0.6,50],[0.1,52],[-1,51],[0,50]]]
      }
    }]
}
```

I change 49 to 50 in the second polygon to remove other points in it.

You can first create a column with the points in `dfr`:

```
#using Point from shapely and apply
from shapely.geometry import Point
dfr['point'] = dfr[['location_lat', 'location_lng']].apply(Point,axis=1)

#or use MultiPoint faster
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
dfr['point'] = list(MultiPoint(dfr[['location_lat', 'location_lng']].values))
```

The second method seems faster on a small dataframe so I would use this one even for bigger dataframe.

Now you can create a column for each polygon in `feature_collection` containing if the point belongs to the feature, I guess by looping on them:

```
from shapely.geometry import shape
for i, feature in enumerate(feature_collection['features']):
    dfr['feature_{}'.format(i)] = list(map(shape(feature['geometry']).contains,dfr['point']))
```

then `dfr` looks like:

```
   location_lat  location_lng              point  feature_0  feature_1
0           0.0          50.0       POINT (0 50)       True      False
1           0.1          50.1   POINT (0.1 50.1)       True       True
2          -0.1          49.6  POINT (-0.1 49.6)       True      False
3           0.4          49.5   POINT (0.4 49.5)      False      False
```

To select which point belongs to a feature, then you do:

```
print (dfr.loc[dfr['feature_1'],['location_lat', 'location_lng']])
   location_lat  location_lng
1           0.1          50.1
```