# Selecting points within a region of a scatter plot

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I have to select values from a scatter plot between two regions. These are defined as the black and the red line. So basically I need all the values of the points between the red and black line.

```py
N = 500
x = np.random.rand(N) * 2
y = np.random.rand(N) * 2.5
area = np.pi*3
colors = (0,0,0)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, alpha=0.5)
plt.xlim(0.0, 2.0)
plt.ylim(0.0, 2.5)
plt.plot([0, 0.8], [1.1, 1.1], 'k-', lw = 2, c = 'r')
plt.plot([0, 0.8], [1.5, 1.5], 'k-', lw =2)

plt.plot([1.8, 1.8], [2.0, 2.5], 'k-', lw = 2, c = 'r')
plt.plot([1.4, 1.4], [2.05, 2.5], 'k-', lw =2)

plt.plot([0.8, 1.8], [1.1, 2.0], 'k-', lw = 2, c = 'r')
plt.plot([0.8, 1.4], [1.5, 2.05], 'k-', lw = 2)

plt.title('Scatter Plot')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
```

[image]

This is just an example for general terms. My points aren't random but come from a dictionary. I do not know how to select the values within that region. Let me know if you have any questions or concerns.

Comment: You could create a polygon from your 6 points and then use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399381/whats-the-fastest-way-of-checking-if-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a filter (as a boolean expression) for the convex region delimited by the 3 red lines:

```
(y >= 1.1) & (x <= 1.8) & (ar * x + br * y + cr >= 0)
```

The equation of the diagonal line can be found by solving a general equation `ax+by+c=0` to go through 2 specific points. The equation will be zero on the line, negative on the 'left' side and positive on the 'right' side.

A similar filter defines the region delimited by the black lines. And the expression `in_red & ~in_black` defines the region of interest. Such a filter can be used to select the points to be drawn, but could also be used to select the points for other calculations.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# line equation of the form ax+by+c = 0 through (x0,y0) and (x1,y1);
# ax+by+c < 0 for points left of the line
def get_line_eq(x0, x1, y0, y1):
    return y0 - y1, x1 - x0, x0 * y1 - x1 * y0

N = 500
x = np.random.uniform(0, 2, N)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 2.5, N)

ar, br, cr = get_line_eq(0.8, 1.8, 1.1, 2.0)
in_red = (y >= 1.1) & (x <= 1.8) & (ar * x + br * y + cr >= 0)
ak, bk, ck = get_line_eq(0.8, 1.4, 1.5, 2.05)
in_black = (y >= 1.5) & (x <= 1.4) & (ak * x + bk * y + ck >= 0)

plt.scatter(x[in_black], y[in_black], s=5, c='k') # inside the black region
plt.scatter(x[~in_red], y[~in_red], s=5, c='b') # outside the red region
plt.scatter(x[in_red & ~in_black], y[in_red & ~in_black], s=5, c='r') # inside red but outside black

plt.xlim(0.0, 2.0)
plt.ylim(0.0, 2.5)
plt.plot([0, 0.8], [1.1, 1.1], 'k-', lw=2, c='r')
plt.plot([0, 0.8], [1.5, 1.5], 'k-', lw=2)

plt.plot([1.8, 1.8], [2.0, 2.5], 'k-', lw=2, c='r')
plt.plot([1.4, 1.4], [2.05, 2.5], 'k-', lw=2)

plt.plot([0.8, 1.8], [1.1, 2.0], 'k-', lw=2, c='r')
plt.plot([0.8, 1.4], [1.5, 2.05], 'k-', lw=2)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]