# check if point (x1,y1) lies in between 2 parallel lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, line, scatter

how to check if black point (p0,p1) lies between two parallel lines - line 1 (x0,y0) line 2(x1,y1) when lines are horizontal and vertical

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RosmP.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVwoc.png

Comment: what have you tried? You can give a self contained example and show where you have a problem.

Comment: You should edit your question to include a [mcve]. If you create a polygon from your four points that form the lines you can determine whether the point is inside the polygon. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399381/whats-the-fastest-way-of-checking-if-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-in-python) for more details.

Comment: What are your plots supposed to represent? The two images are identical and neither contain horizontal nor vertical lines.