# filter a dataframe with rows inside a polygon

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns of x, y, data. and I have a list for polygon coordinate like this: polygon=[x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4]

I'd like to filter out all the rows of dataframe with (x,y) outside the polygon

```
df.columns=['x','y','data']
polygon=[x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4]

df_1= df inside polygon
```

How to implement the last line? Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399381/whats-the-fastest-way-of-checking-if-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Shapely](https://github.com/shapely/shapely):

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon

df['point'] = df.apply(lambda row: Point(row['x'],row['y']),axis=1)
polygon = Polygon([(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), (x4,y4)])
df_1 = df[df['point'].apply(polygon.contains)].copy()
```

Comment: Yes I saw it but was thinking to not use Shapely. Ok I installed Shapely now. Not I got another error for the first line, TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>, any siggestion.  In my dataframe, there is 3 columns, x, y and data

Comment: Can you do: df['x'] = df['x'].astype(float) and df['y'] = df['y'].astype(float) ?

Comment: the same error, I think the problem is lambda row: Point(row["x"],row["y"], row['x'] is a series)

Comment: if you get this error it means that some of your x and/or y are not floating point numbers.

Comment: I check it:, they are all float type, here is the output by doing df.info():  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 9668 entries, 0 to 12849
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------    --------------  -----  
 0   X         9668 non-null   float64
 1   Y         9668 non-null   float64

Comment: Hi if I just do this, then it is fine, df = df.assign(point = lambda row: row["X"]+row["Y"])

Comment: sorry my bad, fixed the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240741/discussion-between-tozcss-and-roudan).

Comment: Thanks tozCSS, yes it works now. I appreicate your help. I am wondering why this one doesn't work? df = df.assign(point = lambda row: Point(row["X"],row["Y"]),axis=1)
i added axis=1 inise assign() and it got same error, why?