# Finding points in a convex hull and assigning true/false

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, convex-hull

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns, `PointsA["x", "y", "z"]` and `PointsB["x", "y", "z"]`.

I can generate the convex hull `ConvexHull(PointsA)` Note I'm assuming this only uses the x and y since convex hull in a 2D function.

I want to calculate if each point in `PointsB` is inside or outside the convex hull of `PointsA`.

If a point in `PointsB` is in the convex hull of `pointsA` then the value `True` is set to a new column in `PointsB["in_A"]`, and if not, then `False`.

So far I have the following:

```
PointsA = pointcloudA[['x', 'y', 'z']]
PointsB = pointcloudB[['x', 'y', 'z']]

Convexhull_of_A = ConvexHull(PointsA)

# which of PointsB are in the `Convexhull_of_A`, assign PointsB['in_A'] == True
# which of PointsB are not in the `Convexhull_of_A`, assign PointsB['in_A'] == False
```

Comment: Let H = h1, h2, ..., hN  be the convex hull, traversed counterclockwise.   Next, consider the line segment h1->h2 and the point p from points B.   If the cross product of h2-h1 and p-h1 are positive, then p lies on the left side of h1->h2.    Do this same check for all hi->hi+1, and iff all sides say "p" is "on the left" then "p" is inside.

Answer (score 1):

[Shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) Library might be what you are looking for, you can consider the output of your ConvexHull as a polygon and check with Shapely  if that polygon contains the point as in the below example.

```
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon

polygonA = Polygon(Convexhull_of_A.points)
# which of PointsB are in the `Convexhull_of_A`
[polygonA.contains(PointB) for PointB in PointsB]
```

Variable names should be lowercase with words separated by underscores.

Look below for answer regarding polygon.

[What's the fastest way of checking if a point is inside a polygon in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399381/whats-the-fastest-way-of-checking-if-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-in-python)