# How to compute which way data points continue beyond an intersection?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, physics, interpolation

Let's say you have two arrays of data values from a calculation, that you can model with a continuos, differentiable function each. Both "lines" of data points intersect at (at least) one point and now the question is whether the functions behind these datasets are actually crossing or anticrossing.

The image below shows the situation, where I know (from the physics behind it) that at the upper two "contact points" the yellow and green lines actually should "switch color", whereas at the lower one both functions go out of each others way:

[image: Intersecting data crosses and anti-crosses]

To give an easier "toy set" of data, take this code for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(-10,10,.5)
y1=[np.absolute(i**3)+100*np.absolute(i) for i in x]
y2=[-np.absolute(i**3)-100*np.absolute(i) for i in x][::-1]

plt.scatter(x,y1)
plt.scatter(x,y2,color='r')

plt.show()
```

Which should produce the following image:

[image: Two intersecting datasets]

Now how could I extrapolate whether the trend behind the data is crossing (so the data from the *lower* left continues to the *upper* right) or anti-crossing (as indicated with the colors above, the data from the *lower* left continues to the *lower* right)?

So far I was able to find the "contact point" between these to datasets by looking at the derivative of the Difference between them, roughly like this:

```
closePoints=np.where(np.diff(np.diff(array_A - array_B) > 0))[0] + 1
```

(which probably would be faster to evaluate with something like scipy's cKDTree).

Should I go on and (probably very inefficiently) check the derivative on both sides of the intersection? Or can I somehow check if the extrapolation of the data on the left side fits better to crossing or anticrossing?

Comment: Are your data points sufficiently dense so that the true curves can be approximated well by lines between successive data points?

Comment: I posted an answer which I think should address your problems but I'm not completely sure. Your example is quite specific insofar as the x values are the same for both curves and the curves are in the form f(x). In this special case, why don't you just have a look how often the difference of both curves changes sign. Wherever it changes sign you can immediately find the zero-crossing by linear interpolation. This sounds so simple, I might be missing something?

Comment: Just to get you right: You know the two curves (given by points) and what to know if they intersect or you know the points and that there are two curves but want to know how each curve goes? The latter would be kind of arbitrary. Without additional information (smoothness of derivatives, somethng else) this might not be solvable in a meaningful way. So what else do you know?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't find the time to respond earlier, busy week. I want to know how each curve goes. Finding close points is not as problematic, as I showed above simply looking for the minimum of the difference between the two arrays is easy. I'll look at your responses later today and select the best answer.

Comment: It's okay that you did not select my answer - I think it doesn't solve your problem. Actually now I think your problem might be unsolvable at all in the given form. Curves that come close can go any way if no constraint is given and the constraint must come out of the underlying physics which we didn't know. Maybe you find something useful but then it is coming from the physics. One could argue that this is not a good question for SO because the difficulty is not the programming.

Answer (score 4):

I understood your **problem** as:

- You have two sequences of points in a 2D plane.
- The true curves can be approximated by straight lines between consecutive points of the sequences.
- You want to know how often and where the two curves intersect (not only come into contact but really cross each other) (polygon intersection).

A potential **solution** is:

- You look at each combination of a line segment of one curve with a line segment of another curve.
- Combinations where the bounding boxes of the line segments have an overlap can potentially contain intersection points.
- You solve a linear equation system to compute if and where an intersection between two lines occurs
- In case of no solution to the equation system the lines are parallel but not overlapping, dismiss this case
- In case of one solution check that it is truly within the segments, if so record this crossing point
- In case of infinitely many intersections the lines are identical. This is also no real crossing and can be dismissed.
- Do this for all combinations of line segments and eliminate twin cases, i.e. where the two curves intersect at a segment start or end

Let me give some **details**:

**How to check if two bounding-boxes (rectangles) of the segments overlap so that the segments potentially can intersect?**

The minimal x/y value of one rectangle must be smaller than the maximal x/y value of the other. This must hold for both.

**If you have two segments how do you solve for intersection points?**

Let's say segment A has two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) and segment B has two points (x2, y3) and (x4, y4).

Then you simply have two parametrized line equations which have to be set equal:

(x1, y1) + t * (x2 - x1, y2 - y1) = (x3, y3) + q * (x4 - x3, y4 - y3)

And you need to find all solutions where t or q in [0, 1). The corresponding linear equation system may be rank deficient or not solvable at all, best is to use a general solver (I chose `numpy.linalg.lstsq`) that does everything in one go.

**Curves sharing a common point**

Surprisingly difficult are cases where one point is common in the segmentation of both curves. The difficulty lies then in the correct decision of real intersection vs. contact points. The solution is to compute the angle of both adjacent segments of  both curves (gives 4 angles) around the common point and look at the order of the angles. If both curves come alternating when going around the equal point then it's an intersection, otherwise it isn't.

[image: Example of intersection vs. contact point]

And a **code example** based on your data:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def intersect_curves(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    """
        x1, y1 data vector for curve 1
        x2, y2 data vector for curve 2
    """

    # number of points in each curve, number of segments is one less, need at least one segment in each curve
    N1 = x1.shape[0]
    N2 = x2.shape[0]

    # get segment presentation (xi, xi+1; xi+1, xi+2; ..)
    xs1 = np.vstack((x1[:-1], x1[1:]))
    ys1 = np.vstack((y1[:-1], y1[1:]))
    xs2 = np.vstack((x2[:-1], x2[1:]))
    ys2 = np.vstack((y2[:-1], y2[1:]))

    # test if bounding-boxes of segments overlap
    mix1 = np.tile(np.amin(xs1, axis=0), (N2-1,1))
    max1 = np.tile(np.amax(xs1, axis=0), (N2-1,1))
    miy1 = np.tile(np.amin(ys1, axis=0), (N2-1,1))
    may1 = np.tile(np.amax(ys1, axis=0), (N2-1,1))
    mix2 = np.transpose(np.tile(np.amin(xs2, axis=0), (N1-1,1)))
    max2 = np.transpose(np.tile(np.amax(xs2, axis=0), (N1-1,1)))
    miy2 = np.transpose(np.tile(np.amin(ys2, axis=0), (N1-1,1)))
    may2 = np.transpose(np.tile(np.amax(ys2, axis=0), (N1-1,1)))
    idx = np.where((mix2 <= max1) & (max2 >= mix1) & (miy2 <= may1) & (may2 >= miy1)) # overlapping segment combinations

    # going through all the possible segments
    x0 = []
    y0 = []
    for (i, j) in zip(idx[0], idx[1]):
        # get segment coordinates
        xa = xs1[:, j]
        ya = ys1[:, j]
        xb = xs2[:, i]
        yb = ys2[:, i]
        # ax=b, prepare matrices a and b
        a = np.array([[xa[1] - xa[0], xb[0] - xb[1]], [ya[1] - ya[0], yb[0]- yb[1]]])
        b = np.array([xb[0] - xa[0], yb[0] - ya[0]])
        r, residuals, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b)
        # if this is not a
        if rank == 2 and not residuals and r[0] >= 0 and r[0] < 1 and r[1] >= 0 and r[1] < 1:
            if r[0] == 0 and r[1] == 0 and i > 0 and j > 0:
                # super special case of one segment point (not the first) in common, need to differentiate between crossing or contact
                angle_a1 = math.atan2(ya[1] - ya[0], xa[1] - xa[0])
                angle_b1 = math.atan2(yb[1] - yb[0], xb[1] - xb[0])

                # get previous segment
                xa2 = xs1[:, j-1]
                ya2 = ys1[:, j-1]
                xb2 = xs2[:, i-1]
                yb2 = ys2[:, i-1]
                angle_a2 = math.atan2(ya2[0] - ya2[1], xa2[0] - xa2[1])
                angle_b2 = math.atan2(yb2[0] - yb2[1], xb2[0] - xb2[1])

                # determine in which order the 4 angle are
                if angle_a2 < angle_a1:
                    h = angle_a1
                    angle_a1 = angle_a2
                    angle_a2 = h
                if (angle_b1 > angle_a1 and angle_b1 < angle_a2 and (angle_b2 < angle_a1 or angle_b2 > angle_a2)) or\
                        ((angle_b1 < angle_a1 or angle_b1 > angle_a2) and angle_b2 > angle_a1 and angle_b2 < angle_a2):
                    # both in or both out, just a contact point
                    x0.append(xa[0])
                    y0.append(ya[0])
            else:
                x0.append(xa[0] + r[0] * (xa[1] - xa[0]))
                y0.append(ya[0] + r[0] * (ya[1] - ya[0]))

    return (x0, y0)

# create data

def data_A():
    # data from question (does not intersect)
    x1 = np.arange(-10, 10, .5)
    x2 = x1
    y1 = [np.absolute(x**3)+100*np.absolute(x) for x in x1]
    y2 = [-np.absolute(x**3)-100*np.absolute(x) for x in x2][::-1]
    return (x1, y1, x2, y2)

def data_B():
    # sine, cosine, should have some intersection points
    x1 = np.arange(-10, 10, .5)
    x2 = x1
    y1 = np.sin(x1)
    y2 = np.cos(x2)
    return (x1, y1, x2, y2)

def data_C():
    # a spiral and a diagonal line, showing the more general case
    t = np.arange(0, 10, .2)
    x1 = np.sin(t * 2) * t
    y1 = np.cos(t * 2) * t
    x2 = np.arange(-10, 10, .5)
    y2 = x2
    return (x1, y1, x2, y2)

def data_D():
    # parallel and overlapping, should give no intersection point
    x1 = np.array([0, 1])
    y1 = np.array([0, 0])
    x2 = np.array([-1, 3])
    y2 = np.array([0, 0])
    return (x1, y1, x2, y2)

def data_E():
    # crossing at a segment point, should give exactly one intersection point
    x1 = np.array([-1,0,1])
    y1 = np.array([0,0,0])
    x2 = np.array([0,0,0])
    y2 = np.array([-1,0,1])
    return (x1, y1, x2, y2)

def data_F():
    # contacting at one segment point, should give no intersection point
    x1 = np.array([-1,0,-1])
    y1 = np.array([-1,0,1])
    x2 = np.array([1,0,1])
    y2 = np.array([-1,0,1])
    return (x1, y1, x2, y2)

x1, y1, x2, y2 = data_F() # select the data you like here

# show example data
plt.plot(x1, y1, 'b-o')
plt.plot(x2, y2, 'r-o')

# call to intersection computation
x0, y0 = intersect_curves(x1, y1, x2, y2)
print('{} intersection points'.format(len(x0)))

# display intersection points in green
plt.plot(x0, y0, 'go')
plt.show() # zoom in to see that the algorithm is correct
```

I tested it extensively and should get most (all) border cases right (see data_A-F in code). Some examples:

[image: Example, intersection of a spirale and a straight line]

[image: Example, sine and cosine]

Some **Comments**:

- The assumption about the line approximation is crucial. Most true curves might only be to some extent be approximable to lines locally. Because of this places where the two curves come close but to not intersect with a distance in the order of the distance of consecutive sampling points of your curve - you may obtain false positives or false negatives. The solution is then to either use more points or to use additonal knowledge about the true curves. Splines might give a lower error rate but also require more computations, better sampling of the curves would be preferable then.
- Self-intersection is trivially included when taking two times the same curve and let them intersect
- This solution has the additional advantage that it isn't restricted to curves of the form `y=f(x)` but it's applicable to arbitrary curves in 2D.

Comment: I borrowed from [How can I check if two segments intersect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838329/how-can-i-check-if-two-segments-intersect) and [Fast and Robust Curve Intersections](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11837-fast-and-robust-curve-intersections).

Comment: There are still a few glitches (especially possible contacts instead of crossings at the segment points. Will weed them out tomorrow.

Comment: I now fixed the code and catched several possible border cases and added some example images. Mission done in my eyes.

Comment: It looks like you just implemented polygon-polygon intersection (it's more efficient to solve the equation system by hand, actually). I believe the OP's problem is that he doesn't know a priori to which curve each point belongs. So he is trying to group the points together to form two curves and he wants a criterion to tell him how to proceed if both curves get close to each other.

Comment: @Stefan I posted a comment asking a bit about clarification but did not receive an answer. I can only answer the way I understand it. Solving manually is a bit more efficient but there are more corner cases (x/y differences  zero) so the code would get much longer. Grouping data points when you don't know anything might always be a bit arbitrary. For this probably more information would be needed. I will ask again for clarification.

Comment: I agree that the question is not very well defined, and the OP does not seem inclined to clarify. My interpretation stems from his "switch color" statement: So in his first figure (first point of approach), he wants that some algorithm actually recognizes that two smooth functions are actually crossing there, rather than two non-smooth functions anticrossing.

Comment: Polygon-polygon intersection can be solved without calls to the expensive `atan()` function.

Comment: @Stefan I think you might be right. I won't delete my answer though because it was a lot of work. Well, if the physics behind tells him that the two curves switched color while in an arbitrary setting everything is possible then only the physics behind can help him (or better sampling). I fear the problem might be unsolvable without further information.

Comment: @Stefan atan is only for very special cases of a shared polygon point in both curves. I didn't find a better solution in this case to separate contact points and real intersection points.

Comment: I believe one uses some properties of the external product (that one has to calculate anyway for the solution of the equations) to avoid the `atan()` call. But it looks like you got a working implementation of polygon-polygon intersection. Congrats! Not easy to get all the corner cases right...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a spline interpolation for the difference function `g(x) = y1(x) - y(2)`. Finding the minimum of the square `g(x)**2` would be a contact or crossing point. Looking at the first and second derivative you could decide if it is a contact point( `g(x)` has minimum, `g'(x)==0`, `g''(x) != 0`) or a crossing point (`g(x)` is a stationary point, `g'(x)==0`, `g''(x)==0`).

The following code searches for a minimum of `g(x)**2` in constrained interval and then plot the derivatives. The use of a constrained interval is to find multiple points successively by excluding intervals in which previous points were.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sopt
import scipy.interpolate as sip

# test functions:
nocrossingTest = True
if nocrossingTest:
    f1 = lambda x: +np.absolute(x**3)+100*np.absolute(x)
    f2 = lambda x: -np.absolute(x**3)-100*np.absolute(x)
else:
    f1 = lambda x: +np.absolute(x**3)+100*x
    f2 = lambda x: -np.absolute(x**3)-100*x

xp = np.arange(-10,10,.5)
y1p, y2p = f1(xp), f2(xp) # test array


# Do Interpolation of y1-y2 to find crossing point:
g12 = sip.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(xp, y1p - y2p) # Spline Interpolator of Difference
dg12 = g12.derivative() # spline derivative
ddg12 = dg12.derivative() # spline derivative

# Bounded least square fit to find minimal distance
gg = lambda x: g12(x)*g12(x)
rr = sopt.minimize_scalar(gg, bounds=[-1,1]) # search minium in Interval [-1,1]
x_c = rr['x'] # x value with minimum distance
print("Crossing point is at x = {} (Distance: {})".format(x_c, g12(x_c)))



fg = plt.figure(1)
fg.clf()
fg,ax = plt.subplots(1, 1,num=1)
ax.set_title("Function Values $y$")
ax.plot(xp, np.vstack([y1p,y2p]).T, 'x',)
xx = np.linspace(xp[0], xp[-1], 1000)
ax.plot(xx, np.vstack([f1(xx), f2(xx)]).T, '-', alpha=0.5)
ax.grid(True)
ax.legend(loc="best")
fg.canvas.draw()

fg = plt.figure(2)
fg.clf()
fg,axx = plt.subplots(3, 1,num=2)
axx[0].set_title("$g(x) = y_1(x) - y_2(x)$")
axx[1].set_title("$dg(x)/dx$")
axx[2].set_title("$d^2g(x)/dx^2$")
for ax,g in zip(axx, [g12, dg12, ddg12]):
    ax.plot(xx, g(xx))
    ax.plot(x_c, g(x_c), 'ro', alpha=.5)
    ax.grid(True)

fg.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The difference function show that the difference is not smooth:
[image: Interpolation of difference]