# Not see through the walls

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to model some building search in Netlogo, but now I am stuck, because I have no idea how to solve seeing through walls. My agent can see in cone lets say 60 degrees and 5 patches ahead. I can detect wall somewhere in my sight and i can detect other objects as well, problem is to detect if the obejct is behind wall or not. How can I solve it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a full working example. You can do some optimizations regarding which walls or patches need to be checked, rather than all of them, but I'll leave that to you...Essentially, You can imagine that you draw a line between the agent and all other patches that are in the vision of the agent and remove the patches such that there is an intersecting wall. The line-intersection problem is well studied and I put a link for you to look at. To make my calculations easier, I store the end points of the wall--you could use trig to calculate the end points if the wall wasn't vertical like in my case. I use some aesthetics too...

```
breed [ walls wall]
walls-own [first-end second-end]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  set-default-shape walls "line"
  crt 1 [ setxy 4 0]
  ask turtles [facexy 0 0]

  ;;color all cones in radius blue by default
  let dist 10
  let angle 30
  ask turtles [ ask patches in-cone dist angle [set pcolor blue]]

  ;; place a wall down...the line of sight is blocked (keyword: line)
  create-walls 1 [ setxy 0 0 ]
  ;;This is an interpretation of a wall. Two points that define the edges.
  ask wall 1 [set size 10]
  ask wall 1 [set first-end (list 0 (size / 2))]
  ask wall 1 [set second-end (list 0 (-1 * size / 2))]
  ;;my wall is vertical. You can do trig above and below to adjust for not vert lines.
  ask wall 1 [ set heading 0]
  ask wall 1 [set color hsb  216 50 100] ;;pretty blue =)

  ask turtle 0 [ ask in-sight dist angle [ set pcolor green]]
end

;;a turtle can see a patch if the line from the patch to the turtle isn't intersected by a wall.
to-report in-sight [dist angle]
  let turtle-x xcor
  let turtle-y ycor
  report patches in-cone dist angle with 
  [
    not any? walls with [intersects [pxcor] of myself [pycor] of myself turtle-x turtle-y  ;; line 1
                                   (first first-end) (last first-end) (first second-end) (last second-end)] ;; line 2
  ]
end
;; See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838329/how-can-i-check-if-two-segments-intersect
;;counter clockwise method (doesn't consider colinearity)
to-report counter-clockwise [x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3]
  ;;returns true if triplet creates counter clockwise angle (uses slopes)
  ;(C.y-A.y) * (B.x-A.x) > (B.y-A.y) * (C.x-A.x)
  report (y3 - y1) * (x2 - x1) > (y2 - y1) * (x3 - x1)
end

to-report intersects [x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4]
  ;;line 1: x1 y1 x2 y2
  ;;line 2: x3 y3 x4 y4
  ;;DANGER: Doesn't work for colinear segments!!!
  ;ccw(A,C,D) != ccw(B,C,D) and ccw(A,B,C) != ccw(A,B,D)
  report (counter-clockwise x1 y1 x3 y3 x4 y4) != (counter-clockwise x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4)
  and (counter-clockwise x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3) != (counter-clockwise x1 y1 x2 y2 x4 y4)
end
```