# How to make an agent/turtle not see through multiple walls? (Netlogo)

Tags: netlogo, agent

I am new to posting in stackoverflow.

Before I had a problem with agents/turtles seeing through the walls I make, but I have found the solution here:

[Not see through the walls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684740/not-see-through-the-walls)

The problem now is when there is another wall within the vision-cone, the valid line of sight (green patches) are incorrect. I'm currently still tinkering on how to fix this.

Here is my current code that I have been working on,

```
breed [walls wall]
walls-own [first-end second-end]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  set-default-shape walls "line"
  crt 1 [setxy 4 0]
  ask turtles [facexy 0 0]

  ;color all cones in radius blue by default
  let dist 10
  let angle 80
  ask turtles [ask patches in-cone dist angle [set pcolor blue]]

  ;; place a wall down.... the line of sight is blocked (keyword: line)
  create-walls 1 [setxy 0 0]


  ;;This is an interpretation of a wall. Two points that define the edges.
  ask wall 1 [set size 10]


  ;;my wall is vertical. you can do trig above and below to adjust for not vert lines.
  ask wall 1 [set heading 45]
  ask wall 1 [set color hsb 216 50 100]

  ;; I made it so that it could consider not vertical lines
  ask wall 1 [ set first-end (list (round (sin heading * (size / 2))) (round (cos heading * (size / 2))))]
  ask wall 1 [ set second-end (list (round((-1 * (size / 2) * sin heading))) (round ((-1 * (size / 2) * cos heading))))]

  ;;Test wall. UN-COMMENT THE SET BELOW TO SEE THE PROBLEM
;  create-walls 1 [setxy 4 4]
;  ask wall 2 [set size 10]
;  ask wall 2 [set heading 90]
;  ask wall 2 [ set first-end (list (round (sin heading * (size / 2))) (round (cos heading * (size / 2))))]
;  ask wall 2 [ set second-end (list (round((-1 * (size / 2) * sin heading))) (round ((-1 * (size / 2) * cos heading))))]
;  ask wall 2 [set color hsb 216 50 100]

  ask turtle 0 [ask in-sight dist angle [set pcolor green]]
end

;;a turtle can see a patch if the line from the patch to the trutle isnt intersected by a wall.
to-report in-sight [dist angle]
  let turtle-x xcor
  let turtle-y ycor

  report patches in-cone dist angle with
  [
    not any? walls with [intersects [pxcor] of myself [pycor] of myself turtle-x turtle-y ;; line 1
      (first first-end)(last first-end)(first second-end)(last second-end)] ;; line 2
  ]
end

to-report counter-clockwise [x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3]
  ;; returns true if triplet creates counter clockwise angle (uses slopes)
  ;; (C.y-A.y) * (B.x-A.x) > (B.y-A.y*(C.x-A.x)
  report (y3 - y1)*(x2 - x1)>(y2 - y1)*(x3 - x1)
end

to-report intersects [x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4]
  ;; line 1: x1 y1 x2 y2
  ;; line 2: x3 y3 x4 y4
  ;;DANGER: Doesnt work for colinear segments
  report (counter-clockwise x1 y1 x3 y3 x4 y4) != (counter-clockwise x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4)
  and (counter-clockwise x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3) != (counter-clockwise x1 y1 x2 y2 x4 y4)
end
```

This is what it looks like if you would uncomment the set of code for the test wall.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqdbL.png)

Any suggestions or tips would be very helpful!
Thank you in advance.