# Check if two lines are intersecting? (if so, not where so)

Tags: line, intersection, gdscript, line-intersection

I saw this asked but I couldn't understand the answers!

I got 4 vector2s, P1 & P2 for line 1, P3 & P4 for line 2.
Code for intersection position works, but how do I check if that intersection is happening?

More specifically, I want to check what side of a polygon an imaginary line is passing through/colliding with

...

...Had something like it working in an old test-script, however I made no annotations and I can't adapt it. I don't know if there's anything here that could be used but thought I'd share:

```
    if rotation_angle > PI/2 && rotation_angle < 3*PI/2:
        if rad_overflow(($Position2D.position-position).angle()-PI/2) < rad_overflow(rotation_angle-PI/2) or rad_overflow(($Position2D.position-position).angle()-PI/2) > rad_overflow(rotation_angle+PI/2):
            actives.x = 1
        else:
            actives.x = 0
            
        
        if rad_overflow(($Position2D2.position-position).angle()-PI/2) < rad_overflow(rotation_angle-PI/2) or rad_overflow(($Position2D2.position-position).angle()-PI/2) > rad_overflow(rotation_angle+PI/2):
            actives.y = 1
        else:
            actives.y = 0
    
    
    else:
        if rad_overflow(($Position2D.position-position).angle()-PI/2) < rad_overflow(rotation_angle-PI/2) && rad_overflow(($Position2D.position-position).angle()-PI/2) > rad_overflow(rotation_angle+PI/2):
            actives.x = 1
        else:
            actives.x = 0
        
        if rad_overflow(($Position2D2.position-position).angle()-PI/2) < rad_overflow(rotation_angle-PI/2) && rad_overflow(($Position2D2.position-position).angle()-PI/2) > rad_overflow(rotation_angle+PI/2):
            actives.y = 1
        else:
            actives.y = 0
```

```
    var point1 = $Position2D.position
    var point2 = $Position2D2.position
    
    var limit3 = Vector2(0,1).rotated(rotation_angle+PI/2)
    var limit4 = Vector2(0,1).rotated(rotation_angle-PI/2)
    
    
    var det = (point1.x - point2.x)*(limit3.y - limit4.y) - (point1.y - point2.y)*(limit3.x - limit4.x)
    
    var new_position = Vector2(
    ((point1.x*point2.y - point1.y*point2.x) * (limit3.x-limit4.x)  -  (point1.x-point2.x) * (limit3.x*limit4.y - limit3.y*limit4.x))/det,
    ((point1.x*point2.y - point1.y*point2.x) * (limit3.y-limit4.y)  -  (point1.y-point2.y) * (limit3.x*limit4.y - limit3.y*limit4.x))/det)
```

```
    if actives.x != actives.y:
        print("hit")
    else:
        print("miss")
```

Comment: I found a solution that worked now:... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838329/how-can-i-check-if-two-segments-intersect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if two segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838329/how-can-i-check-if-two-segments-intersect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> I got 4 vector2s, P1 & P2 for line 1, P3 & P4 for line 2. Code for intersection position works, but how do I check if that intersection is happening?

If you are using Godot, you can use the `Geometry` class for this, in particular the `line_intersects_line_2d` method. I quote from the documentation:

> `Variant line_intersects_line_2d ( Vector2 from_a, Vector2 dir_a, Vector2 from_b, Vector2 dir_b )`
>
> Checks if the two lines (from_a, dir_a) and (from_b, dir_b) intersect. If yes, return the point of intersection as Vector2. If no intersection takes place, returns null.
>
> Note: The lines are specified using direction vectors, not end points.

So that gives you both if they intersect (if it returns `null` they don't intersect) and where (if it does not return `null` it returns a `Vector2` with the position of the intersection).