# How do I compute the intersection point of two lines?

Tags: python, geometry, line, intersect

I have two lines that intersect at a point.  I know the endpoints of the two lines.  How do I compute the intersection point in Python?

```
# Given these endpoints
#line 1
A = [X, Y]
B = [X, Y]

#line 2
C = [X, Y]
D = [X, Y]

# Compute this:
point_of_intersection = [X, Y]
```

Comment: Are these line segments, or lines?

Comment: This problem mostly boils down to "do the math". You can use algebraic manipulation to find an expression for the coordinates of the intersection, then insert that expression into your program. Remember to check for parallel lines first, though.

Comment: Search stackoverflow before ask a question : [the answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252194/numpy-and-line-intersections

Comment: *“I know how to do this on paper”* — Then what exactly is your problem? It’s pure math which you need to apply here. And Python is your calculator. What have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if two segments intersect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838329/how-can-i-check-if-two-segments-intersect)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Unlike other suggestions, this is short and doesn't use external libraries like `numpy`. (Not that using other libraries is bad...it's nice not need to, especially for such a simple problem.)

```
def line_intersection(line1, line2):
    xdiff = (line1[0][0] - line1[1][0], line2[0][0] - line2[1][0])
    ydiff = (line1[0][1] - line1[1][1], line2[0][1] - line2[1][1])

    def det(a, b):
        return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]

    div = det(xdiff, ydiff)
    if div == 0:
       raise Exception('lines do not intersect')

    d = (det(*line1), det(*line2))
    x = det(d, xdiff) / div
    y = det(d, ydiff) / div
    return x, y

print line_intersection((A, B), (C, D))
```

And FYI, I would use tuples instead of lists for your points. E.g.

```
A = (X, Y)
```

---

EDIT: Initially there was a typo. That was [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20677983/8) Sept 2014 thanks to @zidik.

This is simply the Python transliteration of the following formula, where the lines are (**a1**, **a2**) and (**b1**, **b2**) and the intersection is **p**. (If the denominator is zero, the lines have no unique intersection.)

[image]

Comment: This solution yields (1.0, 2.0) for intersecting `line_intersection(((0.5, 0.5), (1.5, 0.5)), ((1, 0), (1, 2)))`, which should be (1, 0.5).

Comment: I have to agree with @xtofl - this doesn't work. I get false positives and negatives.

Comment: Î would also avoid using exceptions here. A simple `False` would do and it's not as expensive as handling an exception.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for points that intersect at (0.,0.)

Comment: Ha! @Pithikos  was about to say that... Reinventing the wheel is only good for learning/understanding and never for implementing

Comment: I would **never** implement code that is already programmed in a library: that is time wasting and you undergo the risk of make a buggy code. As @user32882 said, the only sense of self implementing is to learn—but that was not the question. I recommend this answer for the [mathematics forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/). ;)

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus I agree. As long as you have a good way of installing, auditing, deploying, and updating your library.

Comment: "using other libraries is bad" what?? but numpy is widely used, and implementation is much nicer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42727584/2580835

Comment: @rbaleksandar, I would disagree.  Using an exception is the way to go based on the return type of the function.  Just because Python allows a function to return multiple types doesn't mean you should.

Comment: As others have noted, this is giving false positives. These lines for instance `((0.5, 0.5), (1.0, 0.5))` and `((0.7471, 0.2936), (0.751, 0.25))` do not intersect. We can easily see that when the lines are graphed, yet the function claims they intersect at '(0.7286376146788988, 0.5`.

Comment:  Great! I also tested it in graphics. The intersection point was  exact! (And I totally agree: avoiding importing modules is always better. It requires more skills.)

Comment: @iperov, but maybe you would like to use PyPy. There are implicit decisions/complications. No bad, but not non-existent either.

Answer (score 91):

Can't stand aside,

So we have linear system:

> A<sub>1</sub> * x + B<sub>1</sub> * y = C<sub>1</sub>
>   A<sub>2</sub> * x + B<sub>2</sub> * y  = C<sub>2</sub>

let's do it with Cramer's rule, so solution can be found in determinants:

> x = D<sub>x</sub>/D
>   y = D<sub>y</sub>/D

where *D* is main determinant of the system:

> A<sub>1</sub> B<sub>1</sub>
>    A<sub>2</sub> B<sub>2</sub>

and *D<sub>x</sub>* and *D<sub>y</sub>* can be found from matricies:

> C<sub>1</sub> B<sub>1</sub>
>   C<sub>2</sub> B<sub>2</sub>

and

> A<sub>1</sub> C<sub>1</sub>
>   A<sub>2</sub> C<sub>2</sub>

(notice, as *C* column consequently substitues the coef. columns of *x* and *y*)

So now the python, for clarity for us, to not mess things up let's do mapping between math and python. We will use array `L` for storing our coefs *A*, *B*, *C* of the line equations and intestead of pretty `x`, `y` we'll have `[0]`, `[1]`, but anyway. Thus, what I wrote above will have the following form further in the code:

for *D*

> L1[0] L1[1]
>   L2[0] L2[1]

for *D<sub>x</sub>*

> L1[2] L1[1]
>   L2[2] L2[1]

for *D<sub>y</sub>*

> L1[0] L1[2]
>   L2[0] L2[2]

Now go for coding:

`line` - produces coefs *A*, *B*, *C* of line equation by two points provided,
`intersection` - finds intersection point (if any) of two lines provided by coefs.

```py
from __future__ import division 

def line(p1, p2):
    A = (p1[1] - p2[1])
    B = (p2[0] - p1[0])
    C = (p1[0]*p2[1] - p2[0]*p1[1])
    return A, B, -C

def intersection(L1, L2):
    D  = L1[0] * L2[1] - L1[1] * L2[0]
    Dx = L1[2] * L2[1] - L1[1] * L2[2]
    Dy = L1[0] * L2[2] - L1[2] * L2[0]
    if D != 0:
        x = Dx / D
        y = Dy / D
        return x,y
    else:
        return False
```

Usage example:

```py
L1 = line([0,1], [2,3])
L2 = line([2,3], [0,4])

R = intersection(L1, L2)
if R:
    print "Intersection detected:", R
else:
    print "No single intersection point detected"
```

Comment: This solution reports intersection where the lines COULD intersect given they have eternal lengths.

Comment: @firelynx I think you are confusing the term **line** with **line segment**. The OP asks for a line intersection (on purpose or due to not understanding the difference). When checking lines for intersections on has to take into account the fact that lines are infinite that is the rays that start from its midpoint (defined by the given coordinates of the two points that define it) in both directions. In a case of line segment intersection only the part of the line between the given points is checked for intersection and its infinite continuation is ignored.

Comment: Btw how about coinciding lines? Using the algorithm above it returns `true` for two coinciding lines which can obviously not return a single point of intersection (since mathematically speaking there are infinite number of intersection points for this case). I think that the algorithms needs to handle this in a separate case since simply intersecting and coinciding lines are two very different cases.

Comment: Yes @rbaleksandar, with this method - when `R` is `true` (`D != 0`) we can say only about intersecting lines. All other cases for `R` (when `D == 0`) can mean anything except intersecting (coinciding or parallel) lines.

Comment: sorry for digging up, but I can't grasp how the values for A, B and C are determined as they are in the first method. can anyone elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: @Applecow: C is the determinant of the line. Refer to Paul Draper answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20677983/501134)

Comment: This solution is also particularly good in that you can find the intersection between two lines when one of the lines is vertical. Treating the line as y=mx + c did not allow me to do this as m=infinity when the line is vertical.

Answer (score 29):

Here is a solution using the [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html) library. Shapely is often used for GIS work, but is built to be useful for computational geometry. I changed your inputs from lists to tuples.

## Problem

```py
# Given these endpoints
#line 1
A = (X, Y)
B = (X, Y)

#line 2
C = (X, Y)
D = (X, Y)

# Compute this:
point_of_intersection = (X, Y)
```

## Solution

```
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

line1 = LineString([A, B])
line2 = LineString([C, D])

int_pt = line1.intersection(line2)
point_of_intersection = int_pt.x, int_pt.y

print(point_of_intersection)
```

Comment: It's important to be aware that this solution only works if the intersection is between the end points defined, as shapely only finds the intersection of line segments, not of the corresponding infinite lines.

Answer (score 22):

Using formula from:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection

```
 def findIntersection(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4):
        px= ( (x1*y2-y1*x2)*(x3-x4)-(x1-x2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4) ) / ( (x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4) ) 
        py= ( (x1*y2-y1*x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4) ) / ( (x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4) )
        return [px, py]
```

Comment: I am using this bit of code with great success. However I am struggling with how to construct a mechanism to tell me if the point is actually intersecting with the finite line segment, and not the imaginary infinite line. So I need to find if the point x,y is anywhere within the space of (x1,y1,x2,y2). 
Any ideas?

Comment: @Mars were u able to find the mechanism to tell if the point is actually intersecting or not?

Comment: @OsamaNaeem Sorry I dont know. Its quite a while ago. I found a solution but I cant remember it.

Comment: this one runs in a zerodivisionerror if the lines do not intersect. could you update it with some try except or something else to give just an exception or return value of None?

Answer (score 12):

If your lines are multiple points instead, you can use [this version.](https://github.com/sukhbinder/intersection)

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
"""
Sukhbinder
5 April 2017
Based on:    
"""

def _rect_inter_inner(x1,x2):
    n1=x1.shape[0]-1
    n2=x2.shape[0]-1
    X1=np.c_[x1[:-1],x1[1:]]
    X2=np.c_[x2[:-1],x2[1:]]    
    S1=np.tile(X1.min(axis=1),(n2,1)).T
    S2=np.tile(X2.max(axis=1),(n1,1))
    S3=np.tile(X1.max(axis=1),(n2,1)).T
    S4=np.tile(X2.min(axis=1),(n1,1))
    return S1,S2,S3,S4

def _rectangle_intersection_(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    S1,S2,S3,S4=_rect_inter_inner(x1,x2)
    S5,S6,S7,S8=_rect_inter_inner(y1,y2)

    C1=np.less_equal(S1,S2)
    C2=np.greater_equal(S3,S4)
    C3=np.less_equal(S5,S6)
    C4=np.greater_equal(S7,S8)

    ii,jj=np.nonzero(C1 & C2 & C3 & C4)
    return ii,jj

def intersection(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    """
INTERSECTIONS Intersections of curves.
   Computes the (x,y) locations where two curves intersect.  The curves
   can be broken with NaNs or have vertical segments.
usage:
x,y=intersection(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    Example:
    a, b = 1, 2
    phi = np.linspace(3, 10, 100)
    x1 = a*phi - b*np.sin(phi)
    y1 = a - b*np.cos(phi)
    x2=phi    
    y2=np.sin(phi)+2
    x,y=intersection(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    plt.plot(x1,y1,c='r')
    plt.plot(x2,y2,c='g')
    plt.plot(x,y,'*k')
    plt.show()
    """
    ii,jj=_rectangle_intersection_(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    n=len(ii)

    dxy1=np.diff(np.c_[x1,y1],axis=0)
    dxy2=np.diff(np.c_[x2,y2],axis=0)

    T=np.zeros((4,n))
    AA=np.zeros((4,4,n))
    AA[0:2,2,:]=-1
    AA[2:4,3,:]=-1
    AA[0::2,0,:]=dxy1[ii,:].T
    AA[1::2,1,:]=dxy2[jj,:].T

    BB=np.zeros((4,n))
    BB[0,:]=-x1[ii].ravel()
    BB[1,:]=-x2[jj].ravel()
    BB[2,:]=-y1[ii].ravel()
    BB[3,:]=-y2[jj].ravel()

    for i in range(n):
        try:
            T[:,i]=np.linalg.solve(AA[:,:,i],BB[:,i])
        except:
            T[:,i]=np.NaN


    in_range= (T[0,:] >=0) & (T[1,:] >=0) & (T[0,:] <=1) & (T[1,:] <=1)

    xy0=T[2:,in_range]
    xy0=xy0.T
    return xy0[:,0],xy0[:,1]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # a piece of a prolate cycloid, and am going to find
    a, b = 1, 2
    phi = np.linspace(3, 10, 100)
    x1 = a*phi - b*np.sin(phi)
    y1 = a - b*np.cos(phi)

    x2=phi
    y2=np.sin(phi)+2
    x,y=intersection(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    plt.plot(x1,y1,c='r')
    plt.plot(x2,y2,c='g')
    plt.plot(x,y,'*k')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: it is obligatory to have `list` or `nd.array`?

Answer (score 7):

I didn't find an intuitive explanation on the web, so now that I worked it out, here's my solution.  This is for infinite lines (what I needed), not segments.

Some terms you might remember:

> A line is defined as y = mx + b  OR y = slope * x + y-intercept
>
> Slope = rise over run = dy / dx = height / distance
>
> Y-intercept is where the line crosses the Y axis, where X = 0

Given those definitions, here are some functions:

```
def slope(P1, P2):
    # dy/dx
    # (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
    return(P2[1] - P1[1]) / (P2[0] - P1[0])

def y_intercept(P1, slope):
    # y = mx + b
    # b = y - mx
    # b = P1[1] - slope * P1[0]
    return P1[1] - slope * P1[0]

def line_intersect(m1, b1, m2, b2):
    if m1 == m2:
        print ("These lines are parallel!!!")
        return None
    # y = mx + b
    # Set both lines equal to find the intersection point in the x direction
    # m1 * x + b1 = m2 * x + b2
    # m1 * x - m2 * x = b2 - b1
    # x * (m1 - m2) = b2 - b1
    # x = (b2 - b1) / (m1 - m2)
    x = (b2 - b1) / (m1 - m2)
    # Now solve for y -- use either line, because they are equal here
    # y = mx + b
    y = m1 * x + b1
    return x,y
```

Here's a simple test between two (infinite) lines:

```
A1 = [1,1]
A2 = [3,3]
B1 = [1,3]
B2 = [3,1]
slope_A = slope(A1, A2)
slope_B = slope(B1, B2)
y_int_A = y_intercept(A1, slope_A)
y_int_B = y_intercept(B1, slope_B)
print(line_intersect(slope_A, y_int_A, slope_B, y_int_B))
```

Output:

```
(2.0, 2.0)
```

Comment: You may want to try this with these points: A1 = [1,1]
A2 = [1,3]
B1 = [1,3]
B2 = [3,1]

Comment: Anything that represents a line with y = ax + b will crash with vertical lines

Answer (score 6):

The most concise solution I have found uses Sympy: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sympy-line-intersection-method/

```
# import sympy and Point, Line 
from sympy import Point, Line 
  
p1, p2, p3 = Point(0, 0), Point(1, 1), Point(7, 7) 
l1 = Line(p1, p2) 
  
# using intersection() method 
showIntersection = l1.intersection(p3) 
  
print(showIntersection)
```

Comment: The point class is very slow, it is converting to fractions.

Answer (score 4):

With the [scikit-spatial](https://scikit-spatial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library you can easily do it in the following way:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skspatial.objects import Line

# Define the two lines.
line_1 = Line.from_points([3, -2], [5, 4])
line_2 = Line.from_points([-1, 0], [3, 2])

# Compute the intersection point
intersection_point = line_1.intersect_line(line_2)

# Plot
_, ax = plt.subplots()
line_1.plot_2d(ax, t_1=-2, t_2=3, c="k")
line_2.plot_2d(ax, t_1=-2, t_2=3, c="k")
intersection_point.plot_2d(ax, c="r", s=100)
grid = ax.grid()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

there is already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51127674/19165716)  that uses formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection) but that doesn't have any check point to check if line segments actually intersect so here you go

```
def line_intersection(a, b, c, d):
    t = ((a[0] - c[0]) * (c[1] - d[1]) - (a[1] - c[1]) * (c[0] - d[0])) / ((a[0] - b[0]) * (c[1] - d[1]) - (a[1] - b[1]) * (c[0] - d[0]))
    u = ((a[0] - c[0]) * (a[1] - b[1]) - (a[1] - c[1]) * (a[0] - b[0])) / ((a[0] - b[0]) * (c[1] - d[1]) - (a[1] - b[1]) * (c[0] - d[0]))

    # check if line actually intersect
    if (0 <= t and t <= 1 and 0 <= u and u <= 1):
        return [a[0] + t * (b[0] - a[0]), a[1] + t * (b[1] - a[1])]
    else: 
        return False
    
#usage
print(line_intersection([0,0], [10, 10], [0, 10], [10,0]))

#result [5.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: If you inspect the more readable and accepted answer of this question you might recognize, that it checks if the lines intersect by calculating the determinant of the x and y diffs.

Comment: i was talking about the one with Wikipedia formula which don't have check point @MaKaNu

Comment: In this case you should add a link to the answer, you want to improve. You can do this using the share button from the answer.

Comment: i was talking about https://stackoverflow.com/a/51127674/19165716 @MaKaNu

Comment: Yes I understand this already after your last comment. But here are a few answers. instead putting the link into another comment you should edit your answer or even better provide an Edit (if possible to the original answer.)

Comment: this worked perfectly i prefer this solution then the top one

Answer (score 0):

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4df2.png)  And You can use this kode

```
class Nokta:
def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x=x
    self.y=y             
class Dogru:
def __init__(self,a,b):
    self.a=a
    self.b=b        

def Kesisim(self,Dogru_b):
    x1= self.a.x
    x2=self.b.x
    x3=Dogru_b.a.x
    x4=Dogru_b.b.x
    y1= self.a.y
    y2=self.b.y
    y3=Dogru_b.a.y
    y4=Dogru_b.b.y                          
    #Notlardaki denklemleri kullandım
    pay1=((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3))      
    pay2=((x2-x1) * (y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1) * (x1 - x3))
    payda=((y4 - y3) *(x2-x1)-(x4 - x3)*(y2 - y1))        

    if pay1==0 and pay2==0 and payda==0:
        print("DOĞRULAR BİRBİRİNE ÇAKIŞIKTIR")

    elif payda==0:               
        print("DOĞRULAR BİRBİRNE PARALELDİR")        
    else:                               
        ua=pay1/payda if payda else 0                   
        ub=pay2/payda  if payda else 0  
        #x ve y buldum 
        x=x1+ua*(x2-x1) 
        y=y1+ua*(y2-y1)
        print("DOĞRULAR {},{} NOKTASINDA KESİŞTİ".format(x,y))
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Euclid** library should also be mentioned.

See: https://pypi.org/project/euclid/ (october 2023)

The Euclid library, as its name suggests, provides classes to define points, lines, segments, circles, and spheres in 2D and 3D, as well as a set of basic operations and methods for working with them. I found the code of the package to be very readable, which allowed me to easily add my own methods.

The following code finds the intersection of two lines:

```
>>> from euclid import Line2, Point2
>>> l1  = Line2(Point2(1.0, 2.0), Point2(3.0, 4.0))
>>> l2  = Line2(Point2(3.0, 4.0), Point2(-5.0, 6.0))
>>> l1.intersect(l2)
Point2(3.00, 4.00)
```