# intersection point of two arrays (as data sets)

Tags: python, arrays, intersection

I have two arrays `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`. I can plot them individually and see the point of intersection `(xi,yi)`.

But I want to find the point of intersection in the code and not by plotting and seeing them. I wrote:

```
idx = Numeric.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(y2-y1))).flatten()
print x[idx]
```

IS there something wrong I am doing?

Comment: Can you share an example and expected output?

Comment: why you are not using set for finding Intersection within two arrays

Comment: This is far from a [mcve]. How are `x1, y1, x2, y2` declared? How can we try to reproduce?

Comment: @ravishankar: can you may be send me a link where it is already described? Thanks

Comment: x1,y1,x2,y2 are output values from a already generated code. There is an intersection point where two lines cross. I see it when I plot the two data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Using the function given in answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677795/how-do-i-compute-the-intersection-point-of-two-lines-in-python) allows you to compute the intersection between the two lines:

```
# Function from referenced question
def line_intersection(line1, line2):
    xdiff = (line1[0][0] - line1[1][0], line2[0][0] - line2[1][0])
    ydiff = (line1[0][1] - line1[1][1], line2[0][1] - line2[1][1])

    def det(a, b):
        return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]

    div = det(xdiff, ydiff)
    if div == 0:
       raise Exception('lines do not intersect')

    d = (det(*line1), det(*line2))
    x = det(d, xdiff) / div
    y = det(d, ydiff) / div
    return x, y

# Sample line arrays
x1 = (1,5)
y1 = (3,3)

x2 = (1,1)
y2 = (3,6)

# Compute intersection
xi, yi = line_intersection((x1, y1), (x2, y2))

# Visualize results
plt.figure()
plt.plot((x1[0], y1[0]), 
         (x1[1], y1[1]))
plt.plot((x2[0], y2[0]), 
         (x2[1], y2[1]))
plt.scatter(xi, yi, c='k', s=50)
```

[image]