# Plotly: How to find and annotate the intersection point between two lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

I am trying to find and annotate the intersection point of two-line using Plotly. I know we can use `(plt.plot(*intersection.xy,'ko'))` to get the intersection point in Mathplotlib, but how can do it in plotly or if it can be done.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

test = pd.merge(ps,uts,on = 'Time')
print(test)

time = test['Time']
omfr = test['Orifice Mass Flow Rate']
qab = test['Qab']

fig = px.line(test, x=time, y=[omfr,qab])
fig.update_layout( title='Pipe stress and UTS (MPa)',xaxis_title="Time (s)",yaxis_title="Pipe stress and UTS (MPa)",
                  hovermode='x')
```

Output of the code:
[image: Output of the code]

Intersection point:
[image: Intersection point]

Comment: @Rajaa Monnapillai My initial suggestion had some errors in the code snippet (bad copy&paste..?) Now it works as intended. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Comment: Hi @vestland, it worked for me and what I was looking for. Btw, how would you annotate the x and the y value instead of stating "intersection". would you just change the value of the name in fig.add_trace to the intersection values?

Comment: I can add that in an edit. Would you consider marking my suggestion as the accepted answer? By now you've also gained enough reputation points to upvote questions and answers. If you find them useful.

Comment: Will do. 5 minutes.

Comment: That should do it!

Comment: @vestland, I have done that and thanks, this is what I wanted. Just wondering how to change the coordinates of the text?

Comment: Ah, I see. You don't specify the coordinates of the text directly, but rather the offset of the text relative to the intersect using  other values for `ax=0` and `ay=-100`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotating and showing the intersection is easy. *Finding* it is the hard part, and my suggestion in that regard builds directly on the contributions in the post [How do I compute the intersection point of two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677795/how-do-i-compute-the-intersection-point-of-two-lines). I'll include a few lines on the details in my suggestion when I find the time. For now, the complete code snippet at the end of my answer will produce the following figure using this dataset:

#### Data

```
   x  y1  y2
0  1   1  11.00
1  2   8  14.59
2  3  27  21.21
3  4  64  31.11
```

#### Plot

[image]

#### Edit - Annotation

If you'd like to change the text annotation, just change

```
text="intersect"
```

... to something like:

```
text = 'lines intersect at x = ' + str(round(x[0], 2)) + ' and y = ' + str(round(y[0], 2))
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Complete code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
# import dash


# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.arange(4) +1
df['y1'] = df['x']**3
df['y2'] = [10+val**2.2 for val in df['x']]

# intersection stuff
def _rect_inter_inner(x1,x2):
    n1=x1.shape[0]-1
    n2=x2.shape[0]-1
    X1=np.c_[x1[:-1],x1[1:]]
    X2=np.c_[x2[:-1],x2[1:]]
    S1=np.tile(X1.min(axis=1),(n2,1)).T
    S2=np.tile(X2.max(axis=1),(n1,1))
    S3=np.tile(X1.max(axis=1),(n2,1)).T
    S4=np.tile(X2.min(axis=1),(n1,1))
    return S1,S2,S3,S4

def _rectangle_intersection_(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    S1,S2,S3,S4=_rect_inter_inner(x1,x2)
    S5,S6,S7,S8=_rect_inter_inner(y1,y2)

    C1=np.less_equal(S1,S2)
    C2=np.greater_equal(S3,S4)
    C3=np.less_equal(S5,S6)
    C4=np.greater_equal(S7,S8)

    ii,jj=np.nonzero(C1 & C2 & C3 & C4)
    return ii,jj

def intersection(x1,y1,x2,y2):

    ii,jj=_rectangle_intersection_(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    n=len(ii)

    dxy1=np.diff(np.c_[x1,y1],axis=0)
    dxy2=np.diff(np.c_[x2,y2],axis=0)

    T=np.zeros((4,n))
    AA=np.zeros((4,4,n))
    AA[0:2,2,:]=-1
    AA[2:4,3,:]=-1
    AA[0::2,0,:]=dxy1[ii,:].T
    AA[1::2,1,:]=dxy2[jj,:].T

    BB=np.zeros((4,n))
    BB[0,:]=-x1[ii].ravel()
    BB[1,:]=-x2[jj].ravel()
    BB[2,:]=-y1[ii].ravel()
    BB[3,:]=-y2[jj].ravel()

    for i in range(n):
        try:
            T[:,i]=np.linalg.solve(AA[:,:,i],BB[:,i])
        except:
            T[:,i]=np.NaN


    in_range= (T[0,:] >=0) & (T[1,:] >=0) & (T[0,:] <=1) & (T[1,:] <=1)

    xy0=T[2:,in_range]
    xy0=xy0.T
    return xy0[:,0],xy0[:,1]

# plotly figure
x,y=intersection(np.array(df['x'].values.astype('float')),np.array(df['y1'].values.astype('float')),
                 np.array(df['x'].values.astype('float')),np.array(df['y2'].values.astype('float')))

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=df['x'], y=df['y1'], mode = 'lines'))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['x'], y=df['y2'], mode = 'lines'))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y,
                          mode = 'markers',
                          marker=dict(line=dict(color='black', width = 2),
                                      symbol = 'diamond',
                                      size = 14,
                                      color = 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.6)'),
                         name = 'intersect'),
              )
fig.add_annotation(x=x[0], y=y[0],
                    # text="intersect",
                    text = 'lines intersect at x = ' + str(round(x[0], 2)) + ' and y = ' + str(round(y[0], 2)),
                    font=dict(family="sans serif",
                                  size=18,
                                  color="black"),
                    ax=0,
                    ay=-100,
                    showarrow=True,
                    arrowhead=1)

fig.show()
```