# tkinter movement object by mouse

Tags: python, tkinter

I’m trying to get the object to move in the direction of the mouse, but I’m not out of line, but I must have written something wrong.

```
from tkinter import *

def MouseMove(event): 
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.bbox(square)
    canvas.move(square, event.x - x2, event.y - y2)


window = Tk()
window.geometry('800x600')

canvas = Canvas(window, width=50, height=50)
square = canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,20,20, fill="red")
canvas.place(x=200, y=50)

window.bind('<Motion>', MouseMove)

window.mainloop()
```

I need the object to move (aiming towards the cursor) within the canvas, but everything is tracked outside the canvas

I tried to solve it this way, but somehow an object in the same direction flies away fast

```
from tkinter import *

def MouseMove(event):
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = canvas.bbox(square) # size object
    c_x = x1+((x2-x1)/2) # center object x 
    c_y = y1+((y2-y1)/2) # center object y 
    pos_x = event.x # center mouse x
    pos_y = event.y # center mouse y
    del_x = 800/50 # window size difference and canvas x
    del_y = 600/50 # window size difference and canvas y
    can_x = int(event.x/del_x)# Mouse position detection in the canvas window
    can_y = int(event.y/del_y)# Mouse position detection in the canvas window

    if c_x != can_x and c_y != can_y:
        i=0
        j=0

        if c_x < can_x:
            i = -1
        elif c_x > can_x:
            i = 1
        elif c_x == can_x:
            i = 0

        if c_y < can_y:
            j = -1
        elif c_y > can_y:
            j = 1
        elif c_y == can_y:
            j = 0

        canvas.move(square, -i, -j)

window1 = Tk()
window1.title("AIEyeGod")
window1.geometry('800x600')
window1.configure(bg='#E6E6FA')

canvas = Canvas(window1, width=50, height=50, bg='#E6E6FA')
square = canvas.create_rectangle(20,20,30,30, fill="red")
canvas.place(x=200, y=50)

window1.bind('<Motion>', MouseMove)

window1.mainloop()
```

but the object is out of bounds for some reason

Comment: The reason everything is tracked outside the canvas is because you are binding the callback function to window. Change `window.bind('<Motion>', MouseMove)` to `canvas.bind('<Motion>', MouseMove)` it will work fine.

Comment: Guys, read carefully what need. Canvas and should be smaller window. The tracking and should be outside of canvas, and the changes should occur only in canvas, namely, moving the object towards the mouse cursor, and in doing so not go beyond canvas, but just stop at the boundaries.

Comment: You need to update your question as what you said, instead of leaving it in the comment. Anyway, you need a little math here, to get the intersection between the canvas boundary(rectangle) and the line from the center of the canvas to the mouse position. If you get the intersection, move the red square to there. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677795/how-do-i-compute-the-intersection-point-of-two-lines) for that.

Comment: In the question everything is specified and written initially after the code. Yes, I understand that the window has its own coordinates, and canvas own, and you need to calculate. This is the difficulty that I can not understand how from the mouse coordinates to understand the direction in which you need to move the object to canvas

Comment: No the question is definitely unclear in its current state. And did you see the question I linked? You can just check intersections for four sides of the canvas rectangle. Isn't it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тему можно закрывать, сам решил. Спасибо за намек relent95

```
from tkinter import *

def MouseMove(event):
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = canvas.bbox(square)
    c_x = x1+((x2-x1)/2)+200
    c_y = y1+((y2-y1)/2)+50
    pos_x = event.x
    pos_y = event.y
    if c_x != event.x and c_y != event.y:
        i=0
        j=0

        if c_x < 245 < event.x:
            i = -1
        elif c_x > 206 > event.x:
            i = 1

        if c_y < 95 < event.y:
            j = -1
        elif c_y > 56 > event.y:
            j = 1

        canvas.move(square, -i, -j)

window1 = Tk()
window1.title("AIEyeGod")
window1.geometry('800x600')
window1.configure(bg='#E6E6FA')

canvas = Canvas(window1, width=50, height=50, bg='#E6E6FA')
square = canvas.create_rectangle(20,20,30,30, fill="red")
canvas.place(x=200, y=50)

window1.bind('<Motion>', MouseMove)

window1.mainloop()
```

Comment: English please. Anyway, you seem to implement an animation, moving the square incremently. If you wanted that, you should edit the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).