# How to find cycles among an array of lines?

Tags: python, algorithm, charts

I have a minimal reproducible example.

Input data:

```
coordinates = [(50.0, 50.0, 100.0, 50.0), (70.0, 50.0, 75.0, 40.0, 80.0, 50.0)]
```

This is what these lines form in the drawing:
[image: drawing]

The task is to find a loop, i.e. a closed region, and display their boundaries in the terminal.

In this case, the result should be as follows (it is represented as [(line1), (line2)]):

> `[(70.0, 50.0, 75.0, 40.0), (75.0, 40.0, 80.0, 50.0), (80.0, 50.0, 70.0, 50.0)]`

I tried the cycle_basic method from the networkx library.

But in this method it is necessary that the cycle vertices touch the vertices of other cycles. But here the vertices can touch any place of another cycle

Comment: Have you considered doing intersection tests between lines? If you added in such points (split the lines around them), then you WOULD have cycle vertices touching vertices of other cycles...

Comment: Hi. It's not clear to me how `coordinates = [(50.0, 50.0, 100.0, 50.0), (70.0, 50.0, 75.0, 40.0, 80.0, 50.0)]` relate to the image. Could you please explain the meaning of these coordinates? Are these (x,y) coordinates? If yes, which is x and which is y?

Comment: @NickGris, There are only current points. I don't quite understand how to find cycles in this situation yet. If you have any ideas, please suggest them

Comment: @Stef, Each tuple is a line. A line can consist of two or more points. Each point is represented in 2d format.  For example, a straight horizontal line consists of only two points: (50.0, 50.0) and (100.0, 50.0). A triangle consists of three points from another tuple

Comment: @BobbyLith: Leave cycles for a moment. Since consecutive pairs form lines, with a bit of maths you can find the intersection. If you find a point, if partway along one of the pair of lines, add in an extra pair of coordinates for that point (correctly generating two lines out of the original). With these extras added in, now every line that touches / crosses another does so at a point in your list. Maybe then `cycle_basic` would be viable... (for a discussion of intersecting, try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677795/how-do-i-compute-the-intersection-point-of-two-lines) ).

Comment: @Stef look at two consecutive numbers as a 2D point. The first line (section) connects the points (50.0,50.0) and (100.0, 50.0), first number representing the x-coordinate, this would be the long line on the diagram. The second "line" (it is 2 sections) goes from (70,50) down to (75,40), then back up to (80,50)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want the [induced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)) / [`chordless_cycles`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.chordless_cycles.html). If so, here is a [primal](https://docs.momepy.org/en/stable/generated/momepy.gdf_to_nx.html) approach with [networkx](/questions/tagged/networkx):

```
points = MultiPoint(list(batched(chain.from_iterable(coordinates), 2)))

lines = [
    line
    for coo in coordinates
    for pop in pairwise(batched(coo, 2))
    for gc in [split(LineString(pop), points)]
    for line in gc.geoms
]

G = gdf_to_nx(
    gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=lines), multigraph=False, approach="primal"
)

cycles = [
    [
        tuple(chain.from_iterable(pair))
        for pair in pairwise(cyc)
    ] for cyc in nx.chordless_cycles(G)
    for cyc in [cyc + [cyc[0]]]
]
```

[image]

Output (`cycles`, *clockwise*):

```
[
    [ # top/green cycle
        (70.0, 50.0, 80.0, 50.0),
        (80.0, 50.0, 77.5, 45.0),
        (77.5, 45.0, 72.5, 45.0),
        (72.5, 45.0, 70.0, 50.0),
    ],
    [ # bottom/red cycle
        (72.5, 45.0, 77.5, 45.0),
        (77.5, 45.0, 75.0, 40.0),
        (75.0, 40.0, 72.5, 45.0),
    ],
]
```

Used input (`coordinates`) :

```
from itertools import chain, batched, pairwise
import geopandas as gpd
from momepy import gdf_to_nx
import networkx as nx
from shapely import LineString, MultiPoint
from shapely.ops import split

coordinates = [
    (50.0, 50.0, 100.0, 50.0),
    (70.0, 50.0, 75.0, 40.0, 80.0, 50.0),
    (72.5, 45.0, 77.5, 45.0)
]
```

---

<sup>[Full code](https://pastebin.com/raw/LuN3EMe4)</sup>
<sup>[Old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78192662/1)</sup>

Comment: This is the correct solution, thank you! But if we add a line ((72.5, 45.0, 77.5, 45.0)) in the middle of the triangle, our triangle will split into two parts. And the boundaries of these two contours should be output to the terminal. But only the boundaries of our original triangle are displayed. Is it possible to implement such functionality? That is, to find all basis cycles, taking into account that some loops are located as well as our original triangle. Data: coordinates = [(50.0, 50.0, 100.0, 50.0), (70.0, 50.0, 75.0, 40.0, 80.0, 50.0), (72.5, 45.0, 77.5, 45.0)]

Comment: I updated the answer using a different approach (*this time using* `networkx`). Can you do the same with your post and update the visualization/coordinates/output based on the details you provided in your comment, please ?

Comment: The only and last problem that arises is when different edges of a loop touch different lines that are in the same tuple. Here is an example data: cordinates = [(60.0, 47.5, 60.0, 30.0), (90.0, 45.0, 90.0, 30.0), (55.0, 50.0, 65.0, 45.0), (65.0, 45.0, 70.0, 47.0), (70.0, 47.0, 96.42789180215709, 44.35721081978429), (60.0, 30.0, 90.0, 30.0)].
Thank you so much for your help, I would really appreciate it if you could help solve this problem!

Comment: You're welcome but the new coordinates (*of your deleted comment*) does not have a cycle. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwoRw.png). Let me test with the last one you provided.

Comment: Check this data pls: [(60.0, 47.5, 60.0, 30.0), (90.0, 45.0, 90.0, 30.0), (55.0, 50.0, 65.0, 45.0), (65.0, 45.0, 70.0, 47.0), (70.0, 47.0, 96.42789180215709, 44.35721081978429), (60.0, 30.0, 90.0, 30.0)].

Comment: So you can have floating points as well ? Seems like we need to add a tolerance.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I do that?

Comment: And by the way, just noticed that the cycles are calculated incorrectly. Only cycles with no subcycles inside should be counted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257226/discussion-between-timeless-and-bobby-lith).

Comment: Hi. Please help me to form a query so that others can understand the essence of my task. I still have not been able to solve it. I want to publish it again, but this time clearer for the others