# opencv - Polyline and rectangle intersection

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to get if a polyline and rectangle intersect on opencv+Python:

```
A = cv2.rectangle(frame,(384,0),(510,128),(0,255,0),3)
pts = np.array([[1300,900],[1750,700],[1000,200],[600,200]], np.int32)
pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
B = cv2.polylines(frame,[pts],True,(244,66,66),7)
```

How can I find if A intersect with B?
Thank you

Comment: easiest is probably to draw each one on irs own image and compute the intersection. But other methods will be faster to process.

Answer (score 1):

Opencv and Numpy don't have direct geometry intersection functions.
You can write your own (see [Numpy and line intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252194/numpy-and-line-intersections)) or a common technique is to draw the rectangle filled with a color and then check if the points along the line on the same image are that color.

Comment: Is there any samples related to "draw rectangle filled with a color"?

Comment: If you specify CV_FILLED  as the line width (or a negative line width) opencv will draw a filled rectangle