# Why are the points displayed incorrectly when searching for the corners of a rectangle?

Tags: python, opencv, plot, hough-transform

Using the Hough transform, I am looking for the boundaries of the any rectangle. Then I try to find the coordinates of the corners and draw points, but it turns out something is wrong. I found intersection using numpy.linalg.solve()

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.transform import hough_line, hough_line_peaks


image = cv2.imread('/rect_pics/5.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
cv2.imwrite("gray.png", gray)

edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 0, 10)
cv2.imwrite("edged.png", edged)

using_angles = np.linspace(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, 1800)

halfspace, theta, dist = hough_line(edged, using_angles)

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
plt.title('Hough Accumulator', size=30)
plt.imshow(halfspace, cmap='gray')
plt.savefig('accumulator.png')

angle_list = []

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 8))
ax = axes.ravel()

ax[0].imshow(edged, cmap='gray')
ax[0].set_title('Edged rectangle', size=30)
ax[0].set_axis_off()


ax[1].imshow(edged, cmap='gray')

origin = np.array((0, edged.shape[1]))
lines = []


def find_inter(k1, b1, k2, b2):
    A = np.array([[k1, -1], [k2, -1]])
    b = np.array(([-b1, -b2]))
    x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
    return x[0], x[1]


for _, angle, dist in zip(*hough_line_peaks(halfspace, theta, dist)):
    y0, y1 = (dist - origin * np.cos(angle)) / np.sin(angle)
    ax[1].plot(origin, (y0, y1), '-r')
    lines += [(np.tan(angle), dist)]
    print(np.degrees(angle), dist)

inter = []

for i in range(len(lines)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(lines)):
        print(f"intersection of lines{lines[i]} and {lines[j]}:", end=' ')
        x, y = find_inter(lines[i][0], lines[i][1], lines[j][0], lines[j][1])
        if abs(x) > 1000 or abs(y) > 1000:
            print("NO INTERSECTION")
        else:
            print(x, y)
            inter += [(y, -x)]

ax[1].scatter([i[0] for i in inter], [i[1] for i in inter], color='b')
ax[1].set_xlim(origin)
ax[1].set_ylim((edged.shape[0], 0))
# ax[1].set_axis_off()
ax[1].set_title('Detected rectangle', size=30)
plt.savefig('detection.png')
plt.show()
```

[example of a rectangle with wrong points](https://ibb.co/BtYR2X4)

Please, help me to find a mistake. I'm confused about it

Comment: What's wrong? The result looks ok to me, the lines that shape the rectangle are drawn red, aren't they?

Comment: Lines are OK. But I try to find their intersections

Comment: What are you confused about. The red line intersections look like they bound your rectangle properly.  What is wrong?

Comment: Again: I need coordinates of these red lines intersections

Comment: If you have the endpoints of a horizontal line and a vertical line, and you know they intersect, like `(x1,y)-(x2,y)` and `(x,y1)-(x,y2)`, then they intersect at `(x,y)`.  It's just geometry, no linear algebra required.

Comment: Did you find and try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252194/numpy-and-line-intersections